# Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI

Tags: python, многопоточность, gui, tkinter

Всем доброго времени суток.
Изучаю возможности графического модуля tkinter на Python. Возникла необходимость одновременного запуска нескольких функций, т.е. имеется, например, две кнопки, каждая со своим функционалом. Нужно сделать так, чтобы окно с кнопками после нажатия на одну из них не зависало и позволяло нажать другую кнопку, незамедлительно запустив ее функцию. Пишу на питоне версии 3.5.2.

```
from tkinter import *

def whilefunc1():
    n = 1
    while (n <= 100000):
        print(n)
        n = n + 1

def whilefunc2():
    n = 100001
    while (n <= 200000):
        print(n)
        n = n + 1

root = Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")

but1 = Button(root, text="press me", command = whilefunc1)
but1.pack() 
but2 = Button(root, text="me 2!!", command = whilefunc2)
but2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну так создавайте отдельный поток для проведения расчетов при каждом нажатии на кнопку. Модуль `threading` к вашим услугам, хотя потоки в `python` вообще не очень...

Comment: Если я  правильно понимаю, то надо написать что-то вроде такого: `but1 = Button(root, text="press me", command = threading.Thread(target = whilefunc1))`

Comment: Threading вроде только для ввода/вывода (из-за gil). Для того чтоб не лочилось нужно multiprocessing.

Comment: А можно все-таки какой нибудь простенький пример? Пробую разные варианты но пока что безуспешно

Comment: что у вас фактически функции делают? (пишут в файл, с cетью работают (IO), GUI обновляют периодически (`root.after()` используйте)  или продолжительное время вычислениями в чистом Питоне занимаются (лучше в пул процессов вынести))

Comment: Вообще я на питоне написал небольшую программу, которая бы пинговала определенные адреса по нажатию на кнопку (на 1 адрес своя кнопка). Собственно мне хотелось в свою программу добавить возможность нажатия нескольких кнопок, чтобы не терять время и не завершать пинг вручную, а сразу же запустить несколько эхо-запросов.

Comment: @MrStilver как ping реализован? Запускаете от root или внешнюю setuid команду используете?  [Потоки не обязательны, чтобы несколько узлов одновременно пинговать](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12102040/4279). Чтобы `process.poll()` не вызывать периодически (например, [используя `root.after(period, poll)`](https://gist.github.com/zed/4067619), можно [эффективно (но сложно в этом случае) SIGCHLD сигнал ловить на Unix](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30281111/4279), или [вызвать createfilehandler, чтобы вывод команды прочитать](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978)...

Comment: ...или переносимо, но затратно для той же задачи [вызывать блокирующкю функцию такую как `process.readline() в потоке.](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288)

Comment: Пинг реализован примитивно. `os.system(command)` где command содержить строку команды. Например "ping 192.168.1.1". Я так понимаю ваши примеры предпологают одновременное пингование нескольких узлов одновременно. Мне же необходимо иметь на каждый адрес по своей кнопке и запускать эти кнопки поочередно, но при этом не блокируя GUI. Одну кнопку на все адреса мне пока не надо, но это только пока, так что спасибо за помощь

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Tkinter: How to use threads to preventing main event loop from &quot;freezing&quot;](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745507/tkinter-how-to-use-threads-to-preventing-main-event-loop-from-freezing

Comment: Я так как-то это обошёл. Я создал ещё 1 файл питона и туда долгий цикл ставил. А кнопка запускала этот файл и осн окно не висло

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Общая особенность GUI программирования в том, что не следует использовать блокирующие функции в обработчиках событий, которые выполняются как правило в GUI потоке, иначе это приводит к "подвисанию" GUI.

В вашем случае вместо `self.status[ip] = os.system(f'ping {ip}')` можно использовать `self.process[ip] = subprocess.Popen(['ping', ip])` и позже проверять статус используя `self.process[ip].poll()` (оба вызова возвращаются сразу, не дожидаясь пока команда завершится). Периодический опрос можно организовать используя `root.after()`, например как в [`start_process()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/4067619#file-progressbar-nothreads-py-L60). Можно избежать опроса, если настроить обработчик сигнала, который вызывается когда запущенный дочерний процесс завершается, [например, на Unix (усложнённая опция в данном случае)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30281111/4279). Cross-platform [пример кода это `QProcess.finished`
сигнал](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24148477/4279) из Qt GUI библиотеки,
который позволяет подключить свой обработчик, который вызывается, когда
команда, запущенная
[`QProcess::start`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start),
завершается (`finished` сигнал реализован эффективно, используя
функциональность, предоставляемую соответствующей операционной системой,
не требуя периодического опроса статуса запущенного дочернего процесса).

Альтернативно, если необходимо запустить числодробительную задачу (CPU-bound), то для этого можно создать пул процессов:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

pool = ProcessPoolExecutor()
```

и использовать `command=lambda: pool.submit(whilefunc1)` в качестве обработчика событий для кнопки (`.submit()` ставит выполнение `whilefunc1()` функции в очередь и сразу же возвращается). Если вы нажмёте 1000 раз на кнопку, то вы скорее всего не хотите запускать 1000 процессов (системе вероятно плохо будет). `ProcessPoolExecutor()` по умолчанию использует все доступные CPU ядра, не запуская излишние процессы. В этом смысле, это решение более предпочтительно чем решения, использующие `threading.Thread(..).start()` или `multiprocessing.Process(..).start()`, где каждое нажатие на кнопку приводит к запуску нового потока/процесса.

Если задача связана с вводом-выводом, то можно использовать [`Widget.tk.createfilehandler()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/tkinter.html?highlight=createfilehandler#file-handlers) или аналогичную функциональность в других GUI библиотеках (например, [`GObject.io_add_watch()`](https://gist.github.com/zed/8a255e81eb87431c0e63#file-show-subprocess-output-io-watch-py)). Вот [пример кода, где `root.createfilehandler()` используется чтобы читать вывод внешней команды, не дожидаясь её завершения](https://gist.github.com/zed/9294978).

Поддержка `createfilehandler()` может быть ограничена на некоторых платформах (Windows), поэтому [ту же задачу можно переносимо выполнить используя фоновый поток](https://gist.github.com/zed/42324397516310c86288) ([попытка использовать socketpair](https://gist.github.com/zed/323e6ed224e39107224fd18fa5734804), чтобы получить переносимый код, оказалась неуспешной: `Popen()` не принимает соответствующий `fileno()` на Windows).

Comment: Вы, сэр, da real mvp.

Answer (score 5):

Можно сделать декоратор

```
def thread(fn):
    def execute(*args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread(target=fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs).start()
    return execute
```

тогда можно вынести(@thread) выполнение функции в отдельный поток, без изменения остального кода

```
@thread
def whilefunc1():  # эта функция всегда будет вызватся в отдельном потоке
    n = 1
    while (n <= 100000):
        print(n)
        n = n + 1
but1 = Button(root, text="press me", command = whilefunc1)
```

если выполнение в потоке всегда, ненужно, то задекорировать можно и так

```
def whilefunc2():
    n = 100001
    while (n <= 200000):
        print(n)
        n = n + 1
but2 = Button(root, text="me 2!!", command = thread(whilefunc2))
```

это избавляет от постоянного объявления threading.Thread

Comment: Нужно заметить, что только один Питон поток в этом случае выполняется в каждый момент (из-за GIL), поэтому эффективно только одно CPU ядро загружено. Автору похоже несколько ping  команд хочется запускать, поэтому потоки могут быть приемлемы по сравнению с исполнением CPU-bound циклов в них. Хотя потоки не обязательны, чтобы несколько задач выполнять одновременно: можно использовать root.after(), и на Unix `root.createfilehandler()`, в том числе в сочетании с `signal.set_wakeup_fd()` (см. примеры кода по ссылкам из моего комментария к вопросу).

Answer (score 2):

Ну в общем-то нашел решение:

Изменил

```
but1 = Button(root, text="press me", command = whilefunc1)
but1.pack() 
but2 = Button(root, text="me 2!!", command = whilefunc2)
but2.pack()
```

на

```
but1 = Button(root, text="press me", command = lambda: threading.Thread(target = whilefunc1).start())
but1.pack()
but2 = Button(root, text="me 2!!", command = lambda: threading.Thread(target = whilefunc2).start())
but2.pack()
```

Однако я до сих пор не понимаю зачем там нужна `lambda:`, однако без нее не работает

Comment: У вас большой пробел в базовых понятиях программирования вообще, раз вы не отличаете просто элемент данных от выполняемого элемента (функция). Аргументу `command` конструктора `Button` необходимо передавать вызываемый объект (`callable` в `python`), именно это и делает `lambda` - анонимную функцию.

Comment: С пробелом в знаниях согласен. Занимаюсь этим совсем недавно. Спасибо за комментарий :) Был бы очень признателен если бы вы могли порекоммендовать какую-нибудь литературу