# Асинхронный запуск процесса Python 2.7

Tags: python, асинхронность, python-2.x, процесс, subprocess

Есть скрипт с входным аргументом, который необходимо запустить асинхронно в отдельном процессе (функция для запуска представлена ниже). На данный момент есть код, однако, он работает синхронно с главным исполняющим потоком и блокирует его выполнение до своего завершения:

```
import shlex
import subprocess
import sys

def CreateSubProcess(script, params):
    command_line = '\"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"'.format(sys.executable, script, params)
    args = shlex.split(command_line)
    script_process = subprocess.Popen(args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = script_process.communicate()
    exit_code = scriptprocess.returncode
```

Как осуществить асинхронную работу скрипта в отдельном процессе с возможностью проверки жизнеспособности процесса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p = subprocess.Popen()` НЕ ждёт завершения процесса. Чтобы проверить статус, не блокируя текущий поток надолго, можно использовать `p.poll()`.

В вашем случае программа висит на `.communicate()` вызове, который не вернётся пока процесс жив или [пока есть вывод, который можно читать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36169571/4279). Существуют разнообразные методы, которые позволяют читать вывод дочернего процесса, не блокируя основной поток: фоновый поток, неблокирующее/асинхронное IO, предоставляемое различными библиотеками [см. ссылки в ответе о запуске программы из GUI (`Widget.tk.createfilehandler()`,  `GObject.io_add_watch()` и другие)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570336/23044). Вот примеры кода, использующие [потоки, fcntl, asyncio, twisted, select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/375427/4279) для чтения строки из вывода внешней программы в общем случае, [примеры кода для чтения вывода из нескольких процессов одновременно](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279). Что выбрать конкретно зависит от конкретной задачи.

Comment: спасибо за подробный ответ! Да, действительно, использование p.poll() решило задачу. По крайней мере, после вызова данной функции и завершения процесса, можно получить его статус код, что мне и нужно было. Спасибо!

Comment: @neo: обратите внимание, что если вы не читаете вывод, то не следует `stdout=PIPE` использовать, иначе вы можете подвесить дочерний процесс, когда буфер системы для канала (pipe) заполнится. Если вам нужен только статус, то [используйте `stdout=DEVNULL`, чтобы проигнорировать вывод процесса](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11270665/4279)