# Прерывание процесса и задержка на исполнение

Tags: python, subprocess

Подскажите, как осуществить прерывание системного процесса на Винде из питона? Допустим, код выполняется до определенного момента, затем винда запускает внешний процесс, который надо остановить и лишь потом продолжить выполнение кода. Так же интересует вопрос, как добавить задержку перед выполнением следующего блока кода?

Comment: Все верно, по большому счету нужен таск киллер. О процессе ,который надо завершить, известно его имя и момент запуска. Связь первого и второго вопроса в том, что перед срабатыванием таск киллера необходима небольшая задержка. Но вообще согласен, можно бы было разделить на 2 отдельных вопроса.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191374/using-module-subprocess-with-timeout

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы *прервать внешнюю команду* через заданный промежуток времени, можно передать `timeout` параметр при её запуске:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(command, timeout=timeout)
```

Если `command` не завершится через `timeout` секунд, то соответствующий процесс убивается и [выбрасывается `subprocess.TimeoutExpired` исключение](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html). Иногда этого не достаточно и необходимо руками *убить всё дерево процессов*, [особенно если вы читаете вывод внешней команды](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36952245/4279). Вот [пример кода, поддерживающий старые версии Питона (Python 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4418891/4279), который показывает как остановить "вечную" внешнюю команду через пару секунд, накапливая  её вывод пока она выполняется. Если вы не хотите блокировать основной поток на время выполнения команды, то существует множество способов взаимодействия с командой асинхронно, чтобы найти примеры кода для разных случаев, [следуйте по ссылкам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/570336/23044).

Если команда запущена вне Питона и вы хотите убить её через заданное время по имени:

```
process = get_process_by_name(name)
try:
    process.wait(timeout)
except TimeoutExpired:
    process.kill()
    process.wait()
```

`.wait()` завершается, если процесс вышел или время истекло—что раньше. Это очень близко к тому [как `subprocess.call()`  реализован](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6ccfed5fe245a4dc2d1c76980a8249e9697df3d0/Lib/subprocess.py#L562-L576).

Существует множество других способов *отложить запуск функции в Питоне*, например, чтобы запустить функцию через `timeout` секунд, не блокируя основной поток всё это время:

```
import threading

threading.Timer(timeout, kill_process_by_name, [name]).start()
```

ещё: [`time.sleep(timeout)` или `time.sleep(interval - timer() % interval)`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/577378/23044), или [`Event.wait(timeout)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22498708/4279), или [используя методы из соответствующих циклов обработки событий (event loop)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279)—что выбрать, зависит от конкретной задачи. В общем случае, чтобы *прервать выполнение функции в Питоне*, см. [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/492519/4279).

Примеры реализаций как можно найти процесс по имени и убить его:

```
import psutil # $ pip install psutil

def get_process_by_name(name):
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        try:
            if proc.name() == name:
                return proc
        except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
            continue
    raise KeyError("Process {name!r} not found".format(name=name))

def kill_process_by_name(name):
    get_process_by_name(name).kill()

def kill_process_tree_by_name_windows(name):
    subprocess.call(['taskkill', '/im', name, '/f', '/t'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import psutil
import subprocess
import time

def proc_kill(proc_name):
    '''таск киллер'''
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == proc_name:
            psutil.Process(proc.pid).kill()
            print('внешний процесс %s который надо остановить' % proc_name)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    proc = 'calc.exe'  # О процессе ,который надо завершить, известно его имя

    for r in range(5):
        print('Допустим, код выполняется до определенного момента')
        if r == 2:
            print('затем винда запускает внешний процесс %s' % proc)
            subprocess.Popen(proc)

            print('перед срабатыванием таск киллера необходима небольшая задержка')
            time.sleep(2)

            proc_kill(proc)  # таск киллер

            print('и лишь потом продолжить выполнение кода')
```

out:

```
Допустим, код выполняется до определенного момента
Допустим, код выполняется до определенного момента
Допустим, код выполняется до определенного момента
затем винда запускает внешний процесс calc.exe
перед срабатыванием таск киллера необходима небольшая задержка
внешний процесс calc.exe который надо остановить
и лишь потом продолжить выполнение кода
Допустим, код выполняется до определенного момента
Допустим, код выполняется до определенного момента
```

Comment: вам это может быть очевидно, но для будущих читателей (и для вас самого через полгода), полезно *явно* упомянуть, используя *слова*, *что* вы ожидаете ваш код должен сделать (кратко: одно-два предложения). В качестве бонуса, можно также упомянуть возможные ограничения/альтернативы, представленному подходу. Посмотрите на [мой ответ для примера](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/579941/23044)

Comment: это мой первый вопрос на форуме и вообще первый по программированию, так что извиняйте,если что нет так. Обладая почти нулевыми знаниями довольно сложно сформулировать у себя в голове вопрос таким образом, чтобы он стал понятен всем, прочитавшим его. Но буду учиться. Спасибо за ответ.