# Периодическое обновление Label в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-faq

Есть мой ужасный код и есть цикл, результат которого должен постоянно обновляться в `tkinter.Label`. Опыта в программировании мало, не могу никак до конца разобраться в классах и областях видимости.

В общем, суть в том, что лейбл, созданный внутри `create_widgets()`, должен обновляться из результата цикла `for _ in range(30)`. Функции внутри `start_reading()` используются только там, поэтому мне казалось приемлемой идеей поместить функции внутрь другой функции (метода?). Нашел [вот этот вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603169/update-tkinter-label-from-variable), но он мне не особо помог, к сожалению.

Теперь я конкретно запутался и прошу помощи. Как исправить код, чтобы решить проблему?

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        ...  # Здесь должен быть лейбл

    def get_resolution(self, handle, client=True):
        ...

    def configuration(self):
        ...

    def start_reading(self, arg):
        a = ...
        b = ...

        def get_area(self, resolution, area, foo=None):
            ...

        spam = get_area(...)
        eggs = get_area(...)

        def get_hash(self, img):
            ...

        for _ in range(30):  # Лейбл должен изменятся каждый раз
            ...              # при изменении result, т.е. 30 раз
            result = ...

        del a  # После цикла должны быть удалены a и b.
        del b  # Только там не переменные на самом деле, а
               # .DeleteDC, .ReleaseDC и подобная ересь

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    app.configuration()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не помню точно, по-моему, instance_label.configure(text='New text') или  instance_label.config(text='New text')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Идиоматичный способ организовать цикл обновления GUI элемента—это [`root.after()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter

def loop(n):
    label['text'] = str(n)
    root.after(500, loop, n+1) # call loop(n+1) in 0.5 seconds

root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(font=(None, 100))
label.pack()
root.after_idle(loop, 0)  # start loop
root.after(5000, root.destroy)  # quit in 5 seconds
# center window
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Весь цикл в функции `loop()`. Ещё пример: [`countdown()` функция](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14040516/4279).

Обратите внимание, что НЕ следует явный цикл с `time.sleep()` использовать, иначе GUI подвешивается/замораживается:

```
#XXX DO NOT DO IT
for n in range(10):
    label['text'] = str(n)  
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Обработчики событий (таких как нажатие клавиш, движение мыши, обратные вызовы (`callback`), запланированные программно с помощью `root.after()`) выполняются в одном GUI потоке, поэтому если поток спит на `time.sleep()` строчке или крутится в долгом/вечном цикле, то никакие другие события не обрабатываются—эффект "подвисания" GUI.

Это код можно попытаться спасти, используя `label.update()` и `root.update_idletasks()`, но вариант с `root.after()` является более гибким и надёжным.

Связанный вопрос: [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568677/23044).

Answer (score 3):

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.label = tk.Label(text='None')  # лейбл
        self.label.pack()

    def start_reading(self, arg):
        if arg:
            self.label['text'] = arg  # Лейбл должен изменятся каждый раз
            self.label.update()  # обновить Лейбл
            root.after(500, self.start_reading, arg - 1)  # repeat the call


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master=root)
    root.after(1000, app.start_reading, 30)  # запустить start_reading после 1000ms
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: +1. Теперь можно `self.label.update()` убрать—достаточно что `root.after()` возвращает контроль в цикл  событий.

Comment: К вопросу не относится, но общие замечания по коду: master параметр нужно либо убрать, либо передать его в Frame и родителя Label также следует явно указать. Лучше не наследовать от Frame вообще, а если он необходим, то делегировать вызовы. Для данного примера вообще без класса можно было бы обойтись—класс тут нужен, чтобы label и root не делать глобальным или явно их не передавать как параметры в `start_reading()`

Comment: @jfs Спасибо за замечания! Построение программы было основано на коде из документации: https://goo.gl/v6QN3P

Comment: @Trajectory: 1- код в документации использует master и явно родителя передаёт. 2- Могут быть [аргументы за наследование от Tk widget таких как Frame, Tk](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7300072/4279). Но [композиция может быть предпочтительна наследованию](https://goo.gl/7TEUW2) (в 90x начале 200x преобладающий стиль ООП злоупотреблял наследованием, что к проблемам приводило). Посмотрите как ООП в современных языках таких как Go представлено. 3- Для конкретного примера с обновлением Label в цикле, фокус должен быть именно на `root.after()` (но это уже дело вкуса, как представить объяснение).