# Sleep и while True в tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-faq

К примеру есть код:

```
def tk_sleep():
    status_send = Tk()
    status_send.geometry('400x340')
    tx_1 = Text(status_send, font=('times', 12), width=62, height=15, wrap=WORD)
    tx_1.pack()
    for i in range(10):
        tx_1.insert(1.0, 'hello world')
        tx_1.update()
        sleep(5)
```

При этом застывает целое окно с виджетом. Как этого избежать?

Comment: в тему: [Обновление Label из цикла в tkinter](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581537/23044)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

При [событийно ориентированном программировании](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) (при работе с графическим интерфейсом, в частности) управление должно периодически (в идеале без больших пауз) отдаваться циклу обработки событий (в tkinter это тот самый `mainloop`), иначе цикл не будет работать, и события не будут обрабатываться (например, окно не будет перерисовываться, не будет реагировать на внешние воздействия, типа кликов мышью).

Обычно возврат управления происходит естественным образом, когда обработчик события завершает свое выполнение. Также немного помогает вызов метода `.update()` (в tkinter) - он принудительно вызывает обработку событий.

Но в данном случае все равно остаются большие паузы по 5 секунд, во время которых цикл обработки событий не работает, и окно зависает, т.к. никакие события окна в это время не обрабатываются.

Стандартный для tkinter способ решения такой проблемы - использование метода `after`, он планирует выполнение указанной функции через указанное время в миллисекундах. Управление не будет удерживаться в обработчике, цикл обработки событий будет нормально работать.

```
from tkinter import *


def do_something(i):
    if i <= 0:
        return

    tx_1.insert(1.0, 'hello world\n')
    # "Планируем" выполнение функции через 1 секунду:
    status_send.after(1000, do_something, i - 1)


status_send = Tk()

tx_1 = Text(status_send)
tx_1.pack()
do_something(10)

status_send.mainloop()
```

Другие варианты:

### Threading

Вынести цикл в отдельный поток. Важно: в отдельном потоке должен работать именно этот цикл, а `mainloop()` оставаться в основном потоке.

```
import time

from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread


def tk_sleep():
    for i in range(10):
        tx_1.insert(1.0, "hello world\n")
        time.sleep(5)


status_send = Tk()

tx_1 = Text(status_send)
tx_1.pack()

Thread(target=tk_sleep, daemon=True).start()

status_send.mainloop()
```

### Multiprocessing

Вынести в отдельный процесс через [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Для данного примера это не имеет смысла, т.к. прямая работа с графическим интерфейсом из вторичного процесса будет невозможна, для постоянного взаимодействия между процессами придется использовать `Queue` или `Pipe`, в основном процессе получать данные и отображать их.

Но вполне рабочий вариант использования `multiprocessing`, например, если в фоне нужно выполнить какие-то тяжелые вычисления, потом вернуть результат.

Также весь код вне функций или классов должен быть обернут в блок `if __name__ == "__main__":`, иначе этот код будет выполнять повторно в каждом вторичном процессе (вообще, это зависит от операционной системы, но для гарантии лучше обернуть).

Ниже пример взаимодействия со вторичным процессом через очередь. Тут видно, почему для данного примера нет смысла этот вариант использовать - для получения данных из очереди все равно нужен цикл, периодически проверяющий наличие данных.

```
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing as mp
import queue
import time


def tk_sleep(queue: mp.Queue):
    """
    Функция выполняется во вторичном процессе,
    периодически посылает данные в очередь
    """
    for i in range(10):
        queue.put("hello world\n")
        time.sleep(2)


def show_data_from_queue(window: tk.Tk, text_field: tk.Text, q: mp.Queue):
    """
    Функция работает в основном процессе,
    периодически проверяет наличие данных в очереди
    и выводит их в текстовое поле
    """
    try:
        data = q.get_nowait()
        text_field.insert(tk.END, data)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass

    window.after(100, show_data_from_queue, window, text_field, q)


def main():
    # Весь "внешний" код оборачиваем в функцию main,
    # запускаемую из блока if __name__ == '__main__',
    # чтобы он не выполнялся во вторичном процессе
    window = tk.Tk()

    tx_1 = tk.Text(window)
    tx_1.pack()

    q = mp.Queue()
    process = mp.Process(target=tk_sleep, args=(q,))
    process.start()

    show_data_from_queue(window, tx_1, q)

    window.mainloop()
    process.kill()  # Убить процесс после закрытия окна


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Пример с запуском вычислений через `Pool` и отображением готового результата:

```
import tkinter as tk
import multiprocessing as mp
from threading import Thread
import time


def function_with_some_heavy_calculations(x):
    """
    Условно, тут может быть какая-то функция со сложными вычислениями
    """
    time.sleep(1)
    return x * x


def process_runner(text_field: tk.Text):
    with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() - 1) as pool:
        results = pool.map(function_with_some_heavy_calculations, range(10))
        text_field.insert(tk.END, repr(results) + "\n")


def run_calculations(text_field):
    # Запуск процессов делаем в отдельном потоке,
    # т.к. Pool.map блокирует поток (ожидает завершения процессов)
    Thread(target=process_runner, args=(text_field,), daemon=True).start()


def main():
    window = tk.Tk()

    tx_1 = tk.Text(window)
    tx_1.pack()

    button = tk.Button(window, text="Run calculations", command=lambda: run_calculations(tx_1))
    button.pack()

    window.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Асинхронность

(Самореклама) также есть возможность использовать асинхронность, какое-то время назад я реализовал свой пакет [`async-tkinter-loop`](https://github.com/insolor/async-tkinter-loop) (`pip install async-tkinter-loop`) для этого.

```
import asyncio

from tkinter import *
from async_tkinter_loop import async_mainloop


async def tk_sleep():
    for i in range(10):
        tx_1.insert(1.0, "hello world\n")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)


status_send = Tk()

tx_1 = Text(status_send)
tx_1.pack()

asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop().create_task(tk_sleep())

async_mainloop(status_send)
```

Асинхронность удобно использовать, например, для отправки HTTP запросов (и в целом при взаимодействии с сетью, например, через вебсокеты), только вместо обычного синхронного `requests` нужно использовать асинхронные [`httpx`](https://github.com/encode/httpx) или [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp). Можно, конечно, оборачивать запросы в отдельные потоки, но через асинхронные вызовы все же работать удобнее.

Comment: Ваш код не запускается

Comment: @Александр, действительно. Поправил.

Comment: Спасибо........