# Бесконечный цикл в Python (tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, разработка-игр, tkinter

Я пишу игру на Python 3 с помощью библиотеки tkinter. В игре мне нужно реализовать систему автоматического заработка. К примеру я купил улучшение, и каждую секунду мне капает определенное количество монет.
Я пробовал это сделать с помощью while True в функции, где при нажатии на эту кнопку срабатывает функция этого самого улучшения, но при нажатии на кнопку у меня просто зависала игра и выключалась. Позже попробовал сделать бесконечный цикл с помощью этого же метода (while True) в самом конце кода, он просто не срабатывал, как будто этого цикла и нету. Ещё пробовал сделать функцию с кодом, который должен был быть в цикле, и я так же в конце кода написал while True, но теперь в цикле была одна строчка - функция с нужным кодом. Это тоже не помогло.
Теперь хочу попросить помощи с циклом. Есть ли ещё способы сделать бесконечные циклы без while True, или как исправить эту ошибку. Буду благодарен.
Вот код (код не самый хороший, я новичок в программировании):

```
from tkinter import *
import time

# глобальные переменные
clicks = 0
put, pat = 1, 0
damages = 1
dps_marker = 0
more_enemy1, more_enemy2, more_enemy3 = 0, 0, 0
more_dps_enemy1, more_dps_enemy2 = 0, 0
price_enemy_one, price_enemy_two, price_enemy_three = 100, 350, 800
price_dps_enemy_one, price_dps_enemy_two = 2, 1000



def money_click():
    global clicks
    global put
    clicks += put
    plusmoney = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
    money.configure(text=plusmoney)


def enemy1():
    global put, clicks, damages, more_enemy1, price_enemy_one
    if clicks >= price_enemy_one:
        more_enemy1 += 1
        put += 7
        damages = put
        plusdamage = 'DAMAGE: {}'.format(damages)
        damage.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_enemy1)
        enemyone.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_enemy_one
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_enemy_one - (price_enemy_one // 100 * 94)
        price_enemy_one += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_enemy_one)
        enemy1price.configure(text=priceplus)


def enemy2():
    global put, clicks, damages, more_enemy2, price_enemy_two
    if clicks >= price_enemy_two:
        more_enemy2 += 1
        put += 5
        damages = put
        plusdamage = 'DAMAGE: {}'.format(damages)
        damage.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_enemy2)
        enemytwo.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_enemy_two
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_enemy_two - (price_enemy_two // 100 * 94)
        price_enemy_two += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_enemy_two)
        enemy2price.configure(text=priceplus)


def enemy3():
    global put, clicks, damages, more_enemy3, price_enemy_three
    if clicks >= price_enemy_three:
        more_enemy3 += 1
        put += 10
        damages = put
        plusdamage = 'DAMAGE: {}'.format(damages)
        damage.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_enemy3)
        enemythree.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_enemy_three
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_enemy_three - (price_enemy_three // 100 * 94)
        price_enemy_three += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_enemy_three)
        enemy3price.configure(text=priceplus)


def dpsenemy1():
    global dps_marker, pat, clicks, more_dps_enemy1, price_dps_enemy_one, money
    if clicks >= price_dps_enemy_one:
        more_dps_enemy1 += 1
        pat += 3
        dps_marker = pat
        plusdamage = 'DPS: {}'.format(dps_marker)
        dps.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_dps_enemy1)
        dps_enemy_one.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_dps_enemy_one
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_dps_enemy_one - (price_dps_enemy_one // 100 * 94)
        price_dps_enemy_one += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_dps_enemy_one)
        dpsenemy1price.configure(text=priceplus)

def dpsenemy2():
    pass



wind = Tk()

imagemonster = PhotoImage(file='Image\\eepp.png')
imageenemyone = PhotoImage(file='Image\\ENEMY1.png')
imageenemytwo = PhotoImage(file='Image\\ENEMY2.png')
imageenemythree = PhotoImage(file='Image\\ENEMY3.png')
imagedpsenemyone = PhotoImage(file='Image\\DPSENEMY1.png')
imagedpsenemytwo = PhotoImage(file='Image\\DPSENEMY2.png')

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 510

POS_X, POS_Y = wind.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - WIDTH // 2, wind.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - HEIGHT // 2

wind.geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}+{POS_X}+{POS_Y}")

wind.resizable(False, False)

wind.title('ExpMasClick')

wind.config(bg='#FFA07A')

money = Label(wind, text='MONEY: 0 ', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 14, 'bold'))
money.place(x=5, y=0)
damage = Label(wind, text='DAMAGE: 1 ', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
damage.place(x=5, y=43)
dps = Label(wind, text='DPS: 0', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
dps.place(x=5, y=86)

enemy1price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 100', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
enemy1price.place(x=70, y=320)
enemy2price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 350', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
enemy2price.place(x=295, y=320)
enemy3price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 800 ', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
enemy3price.place(x=520, y=320)

dpsenemy1price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 200', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
dpsenemy1price.place(x=150, y=465)
dpsenemy2price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 1000', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
dpsenemy2price.place(x=440, y=465)

monster = Button(wind, image=imagemonster, bd=0, bg='#FFA07A', activebackground='#FFA07A',
                 command=money_click)
monster.place(x=250, y=5)
enemyone = Button(wind, text='0', image=imageenemyone, bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                  compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=enemy1)
enemyone.place(x=40, y=215)
enemytwo = Button(wind, text='0', image=imageenemytwo, bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                  compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=enemy2)
enemytwo.place(x=265, y=215)
enemythree = Button(wind, text='0', image=imageenemythree, bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                    compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=enemy3)
enemythree.place(x=490, y=215)

dps_enemy_one = Button(wind, text='0', image=imagedpsenemyone, bd=4, bg='#FFA03A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                       compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=dpsenemy1)
dps_enemy_one.place(x=85, y=360)

dps_enemy_two = Button(wind, text='0', image=imagedpsenemytwo, bd=4, bg='#FFA03A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                       compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=dpsenemy2)
dps_enemy_two.place(x=375, y=360)

ex = Button(wind, text='QUIT', bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', activebackground='#FFA07A', padx='10',
            font=('segoe print', 9, 'bold'))
ex['command'] = quit
ex.place(x=630, y=5)

wind.mainloop()
```

1

Comment: Надо отдельный поток как-то запускать. Циклы при нажатии на кнопку вешают интерфейс практически в любом языке программирования.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Sleep в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633670/sleep-%d0%b2-tkinter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена с помощью метода **after()**
Вот измененный код с решенной задачей:

```
from tkinter import *

clicks = 0
put, pat = 1, 0
damages = 1
dps_marker = 0
more_enemy1, more_enemy2, more_enemy3 = 0, 0, 0
more_dps_enemy1, more_dps_enemy2 = 0, 0
price_enemy_one, price_enemy_two, price_enemy_three = 100, 350, 800
price_dps_enemy_one, price_dps_enemy_two = 2, 1000


def money_click():
    global clicks
    global put
    clicks += put
    plusmoney = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
    money.configure(text=plusmoney)


def enemy1():
    global put, clicks, damages, more_enemy1, price_enemy_one
    if clicks >= price_enemy_one:
        more_enemy1 += 1
        put += 3
        damages = put
        plusdamage = 'DAMAGE: {}'.format(damages)
        damage.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_enemy1)
        enemyone.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_enemy_one
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_enemy_one - (price_enemy_one // 100 * 94)
        price_enemy_one += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_enemy_one)
        enemy1price.configure(text=priceplus)


def enemy2():
    global put, clicks, damages, more_enemy2, price_enemy_two
    if clicks >= price_enemy_two:
        more_enemy2 += 1
        put += 5
        damages = put
        plusdamage = 'DAMAGE: {}'.format(damages)
        damage.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_enemy2)
        enemytwo.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_enemy_two
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_enemy_two - (price_enemy_two // 100 * 94)
        price_enemy_two += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_enemy_two)
        enemy2price.configure(text=priceplus)


def enemy3():
    global put, clicks, damages, more_enemy3, price_enemy_three
    if clicks >= price_enemy_three:
        more_enemy3 += 1
        put += 10
        damages = put
        plusdamage = 'DAMAGE: {}'.format(damages)
        damage.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_enemy3)
        enemythree.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_enemy_three
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_enemy_three - (price_enemy_three // 100 * 94)
        price_enemy_three += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_enemy_three)
        enemy3price.configure(text=priceplus)


def dpsenemy1():
    global dps_marker, pat, clicks, more_dps_enemy1, price_dps_enemy_one, money
    if clicks >= price_dps_enemy_one:
        more_dps_enemy1 += 1
        pat += 3
        dps_marker = pat
        plusdamage = 'DPS: {}'.format(dps_marker)
        dps.configure(text=plusdamage)
        plusmast = '{}'.format(more_dps_enemy1)
        dps_enemy_one.configure(text=plusmast)
        clicks -= price_dps_enemy_one
        minus_dollars = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
        money.configure(text=minus_dollars)
        result_percent = price_dps_enemy_one - (price_dps_enemy_one // 100 * 94)
        price_dps_enemy_one += result_percent
        priceplus = 'PRICE: {}'.format(price_dps_enemy_one)
        dpsenemy1price.configure(text=priceplus)


def recursion():
    global clicks, pat, money
    clicks += pat
    plusmone = 'MONEY: {}'.format(clicks)
    money.configure(text=plusmone)
    wind.after(1000, recursion)


def dpsenemy2():
    pass


wind = Tk()

imagemonster = PhotoImage(file='Image\\eepp.png')
imageenemyone = PhotoImage(file='Image\\ENEMY1.png')
imageenemytwo = PhotoImage(file='Image\\ENEMY2.png')
imageenemythree = PhotoImage(file='Image\\ENEMY3.png')
imagedpsenemyone = PhotoImage(file='Image\\DPSENEMY1.png')
imagedpsenemytwo = PhotoImage(file='Image\\DPSENEMY2.png')

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 550

POS_X, POS_Y = wind.winfo_screenwidth() // 2 - WIDTH // 2, wind.winfo_screenheight() // 2 - HEIGHT // 2
wind.geometry(f"{WIDTH}x{HEIGHT}+{POS_X}+{POS_Y}")

wind.resizable(False, False)
wind.title('ExpMasClick')
wind.config(bg='#FFA07A')

money = Label(wind, text='MONEY: 0 ', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 14, 'bold'))
money.place(x=5, y=0)
damage = Label(wind, text='DAMAGE: 1 ', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
damage.place(x=5, y=43)
dps = Label(wind, text='DPS: 0', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
dps.place(x=5, y=86)

enemy1price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 100', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
enemy1price.place(x=70, y=360)
enemy2price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 350', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
enemy2price.place(x=295, y=360)
enemy3price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 800 ', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
enemy3price.place(x=520, y=360)

dpsenemy1price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 200', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
dpsenemy1price.place(x=150, y=505)
dpsenemy2price = Label(wind, text='PRICE: 1000', bg='#FFA06A', font=('segoe print', 13, 'bold'))
dpsenemy2price.place(x=440, y=505)

monster = Button(wind, image=imagemonster, bd=0, bg='#FFA07A', activebackground='#FFA07A',
                 command=money_click)
monster.place(x=250, y=5)
enemyone = Button(wind, text='0', image=imageenemyone, bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                  compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=enemy1)
enemyone.place(x=40, y=255)
enemytwo = Button(wind, text='0', image=imageenemytwo, bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                  compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=enemy2)
enemytwo.place(x=265, y=255)
enemythree = Button(wind, text='0', image=imageenemythree, bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                    compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=enemy3)
enemythree.place(x=490, y=255)

dps_enemy_one = Button(wind, text='0', image=imagedpsenemyone, bd=4, bg='#FFA03A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                       compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=dpsenemy1)
dps_enemy_one.place(x=85, y=400)

dps_enemy_two = Button(wind, text='0', image=imagedpsenemytwo, bd=4, bg='#FFA03A', padx=6, activebackground='#FFA07A',
                       compound='bottom', font=('segoe print', 15, 'bold'), command=dpsenemy2)
dps_enemy_two.place(x=375, y=400)

ex = Button(wind, text='QUIT', bd=4, bg='#FFA05A', activebackground='#FFA07A', padx='10',
            font=('segoe print', 9, 'bold'))
ex['command'] = quit
ex.place(x=630, y=5)

recursion()

wind.mainloop()
```