# Бесконечный цикл в Python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы, tkinter

Я пишу небольшую утилиту для закрытия процессов автоматически. И столкнулся с проблемой циклов. Так как весь графический интерфейс это и есть один большой бесконечный цикл, при включении дополнительного цикла вес интерфейс залагивает. Так вот, нужно, чтобы он не залагивал и работал дальше.
Вот код ( Я новичок в программировании и этот код может быть плохим. Знаю) :

```
print("Запуск...", end='')
from tkinter import *
import time
import os
import pyautogui as pg
import subprocess as sp
print('ok! ')

#Functions


def logicp(event):
    def_name=name.get()
    def_text=text.get()
    try:
        def_delay=delay.get()
        def_delay=int(def_delay)
    except:
        work['text']=''.join("Можно только число!")
        time.sleep(4)
        work['text']=''.join("Остановлено")
    if (def_name and def_text and def_delay):
        work['text']=''.join("Работа...")
        while 1:
            print("Проверка...")
            time.sleep(def_delay)
            tasks=sp.getoutput('tasklist');
            if 'Zoom.exe' in tasks:
                os.system('taskkill /f /im Zoom.exe')
                pg.alert(str(def_text), str(def_name))
    else:
        pass

root=Tk()

root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
root.geometry('400x300')
root.title('Zoom parser')

work=Label(text='Остановлено', font='Consolas 10')
start=Button(root, text='Начать')

#enters

text=Entry(root, width=30)
textl=Label(text='Текст', font='Consolas 10')
name=Entry(root, width=30)
namel=Label(text='Имя окна', font='Consolas 10')
delay=Entry(root, width=10)
delayl=Label(text='Задержка', font='Consolas 10')


#Packer

work.pack()
start.pack()
textl.pack()
text.pack()
namel.pack(side=RIGHT)
name.pack(side=RIGHT)
delayl.pack(side=LEFT)
delay.pack(side=LEFT)

#Binds

start.bind("<Button-1>", logicp)

root.mainloop()
```

Без цикла в функции `logicp()` не получится! А без `root.mainloop()` программа сразу будет закрываться.

Comment: Второй цикл поместить в отдельный поток, смотреть `threading.Thread`

Comment: Используйте метод root.after вместо бесконечного цикла со sleep. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633670/sleep-%D0%B2-tkinter

Answer (score 2):

ваш код:

```
if (def_name and def_text and def_delay):
    work['text']=''.join("Работа...")
    while 1:
        print("Проверка...")
        time.sleep(def_delay)
        tasks=sp.getoutput('tasklist');
        if 'Zoom.exe' in tasks:
            os.system('taskkill /f /im Zoom.exe')
            pg.alert(str(def_text), str(def_name))
```

Замените на:

```
if (def_name and def_text and def_delay):
    work['text']=''.join("Работа...")

    def nameofyourpodprogrammi():
        print("Проверка...")
        tasks=sp.getoutput('tasklist');
        if 'Zoom.exe' in tasks:
            os.system('taskkill /f /im Zoom.exe')
            pg.alert(str(def_text), str(def_name))
        root.after(def_delay,nameofyourpodprogrammi)

    nameofyourpodprogrammi()
```