# Python(tkinter)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Как сделать чтобы окно во время работы программы, увеличивалось? А после 10 секунд исчезло?
Пробывал использовать sleep(), не помагает, он блочит всю программу.

Comment: `root.after(lambda: <your code>)`

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Sleep в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633670/sleep-%d0%b2-tkinter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте метод after:

```
root.after(lambda: <your code>)
```

Comment: как можно двигать окно по кругу? изменяя координаты окна в цикле?