# Хочу чтобы в окно ТК выводило текст через multiprocessing .Но при запуске ничего не происходит(

Tags: python, tkinter, gui, multiprocessing

```
from tkinter import *

import time

import multiprocessing

window = Tk()

window.title("Info_window")
window.geometry("1280x720")
window.resizable(False,False)
canvas1 = Canvas(window, width=1800, height=1800)
canvas1.pack()
mytext = "надпис" 
 

def function(a):
    window.update()
    label = Label(text= a)
    label.pack(


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target= function, args=(mytext,))
    p.start()


    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Не получится, вторичный процесс не имеет доступа к виджетам в основном процессе. Если нужно будет постоянное взаимодействие, например, то делать через Pipe или Queue, в основном процессе нужен будет "слушатель" поступающих данных, отображающий их в графическом интерфейсе. Если не нужно - просто запускать  через Pool в отдельном потоке, потом результат отображать в графическом интерфейсе.

Comment: Добавил в этот ответ пару примеров как можно использовать multiprocessing с tkinter: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365