# Зависает при добавлении строки в таблицу Treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

Когда должна добавиться строка, то программа зависает. Если ничего не добавляется, то нормально. Что не так? Сильно тапками не кидайте, только учусь, первая программа. Всю голову сломал что тут не так. Подозреваю что-то тут:

```
result_tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(ip, hostname, port, "Открыт"))
```

Но не уверен. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
import socket
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def scan(ip, port):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(1)
        sock.connect((ip, port))
        hostname = socket.gethostbyaddr(ip)[0]
        print(f"{ip} ({hostname}):{port} is open")
        result_tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(ip, hostname, port, "Открыт"))
        sock.close()
    except:
        pass

def start_scan(ip_range, start_port, end_port):
    threads = []
    for i in range(1, 255):
        ip = f"{ip_range}.{i}"
        for port in range(start_port, end_port+1):
            t = threading.Thread(target=scan, args=(ip, port))
            threads.append(t)
            t.start()
    for t in threads:
        t.join()

def scan_button_clicked():
    ip_range = ip_entry.get()
    start_port = int(start_port_entry.get())
    end_port = int(end_port_entry.get())
    result_tree.delete(*result_tree.get_children())
    start_scan(ip_range, start_port, end_port)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Сканер портов")

ip_label = tk.Label(root, text="Диапазон IP-адресов:")
ip_entry = tk.Entry(root)
ip_entry.insert(0, "192.168.0")
start_port_label = tk.Label(root, text="Начальный порт:")
start_port_entry = tk.Entry(root)
start_port_entry.insert(0, "1")
end_port_label = tk.Label(root, text="Конечный порт:")
end_port_entry = tk.Entry(root)
end_port_entry.insert(0, "65535")
scan_button = tk.Button(root, text="Сканировать", command=scan_button_clicked)

result_tree = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=("IP-адрес", "Имя хоста", "Порт", "Статус"))
result_tree.heading("#0", text="")
result_tree.heading("IP-адрес", text="IP-адрес")
result_tree.heading("Имя хоста", text="Имя хоста")
result_tree.heading("Порт", text="Порт")
result_tree.heading("Статус", text="Статус")

ip_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
ip_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
start_port_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
start_port_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)
end_port_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
end_port_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)
scan_button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)
result_tree.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Планируется сканировать устройства в сети и при обнаружении нужных подключаться к ним по API. Диапазон портов конечно указывается малый, до 100. И если ничего нет, то ничего и не добавляется. Но если есть, в консоль пишет, что нашел несколько, но не добавляет в таблицу и GUI виснет. ПРоцессор не занят, память не растёт. Просто всё встаёт.

Comment: У вас основной поток блокируется из-за join. Чтобы понимать, когда потоки закончились, лучше сделать чтобы сами потоки как-то отображали в GUI информацию о своем завершении. Либо в основном потоке через root.after периодически проверять состояние всех потоков.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за ответ. Может чего не понимаю... Если закоментить result_tree.insert, то не виснет ничего. Чуть потупит, пишет в консоль что нашел, ещё чуть повисит (так полагаю, что как раз и ждёт завершения потоков) и gui отвисает. Почему не работает когда пытаешься добавить в таблицу то не пойму... Если вас не затруднит, не могли бы вы точно написать код и куда его воткнуть.

Comment: Попробуйте для начала просто убрать цикл с `t.join()`. Потоки завершатся сами и без этого, в основном потоке их завершения ждать не нужно.

Comment: Еще, `except: pass` - вот так никогда делать не нужно. Либо конкретное исключение ловите, и выводите что ошибка произошла, либо делайте `except Exception` с выводом текста исключения в консоль или в логи. А то у вас вылетит исключение, и вы об этом не узнаете.

Comment: @insolor, Ура! Заработало!! :-) Огромное спасибо!!! Про pass и join в хэлпе каком то прочитал, думал так надо. Я уже и так и сяк тыкал, забил. Вы прямо гуру. :-)

Comment: `except:` без указания типа исключения — это что-то из серии вредных советов. В принципе если игнорировать какое-то исключение, то какое-то конкретное. Использование join в принципе вполне нормально, но только если нужно дождаться завершения потока, а использовании графического интерфейса наоборот нужно не дожидаться, и не блокировать основной поток.

Comment: @insolor, Спасибо, учту. Вернусь ещё к этому. Надо будет добавить прогресс и статус. Но вот сейчас, раз уж пошла такая жара, не подскажете как после завершения память очистить? Если ставить 1000 портов, то после завершения программа занимает полгига памяти!

Comment: И тут ещё такой затык, кнопку остановить то добавил, но вот как её нажать, если GUI в процессе висит и с прогресс баром и статусом тоже засада. Как их сделать то в многопоточности при зависшем gui... Т.е. прогресс и статус меняется уже после цикла потоков, хотя изменения стоят внутри него. Ну а когда отвисает кнопка остановить, она уже не нужна, всё же уже кончилось...

Comment: Не допускать зависания gui, т.е. не допускать блокирования основного потока. По поводу памяти — теоретически потоки должны завершиться и вся связанная с ними память. Но возможно у вас где-то утечка памяти, или просто сборщик мусора не сразу срабатывает. По поводу обновления состояния виджетов - в потоках пробуйте `root.update()` добавить после действий с графическим интерфейсом, это принудительно обновляет окно.

Comment: Еще, посмотрите этот ответ, там не совсем связано с вашим случаем, но в целом объясняется про событийно-ориентированное программирование и про взаимодействие tkinter с потоками и процессами: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365

Comment: @insolor, Вот как его не блокировать, если используется многопоточность... Если по очереди то тут всё понятно... Тот же root.update() попробовать... Интересная статья, почти то что надо. Ещё раз спасибо! Буду пробовать и дальше изучать. :-)