# Ошибка TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object при вызове метода через multiprocessing

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

Пытаюсь вызвать параллельную задачу, чтобы не зависало окно tkinter. Но просто вечно ругается. Уже и код переделал под запуск из `__main__` и все равно ему что-то не нравится.

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

class testing(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        pool = Pool(1)
        iup = pool.map(self.check, range(1)) # на эту строку ругается
        pool.close()
        print(iup)

    def check(self, iter):
        return 'good'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = ttk.Window(title="test", size=[800, 600], resizable=[0, 0])
    app = testing(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Ошибка:

```
  File "D:\Program\all\main.py", line 9, in __init__
    iup = pool.map(self.check, range(1))
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 364, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 537, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "C:\Users\Name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
TypeError: cannot pickle '_tkinter.tkapp' object
```

Конечно код длиннее, но  свел все к минимуму

Comment: В итоге чтобы окно не зависало, придется еще Pool запускать в отдельном потоке. См. тут примеры https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы запустить метод в отдельном процессе, нужно передать в процесс все данные, связанные с этим методом, а обычный метод буквально привязан (bound) к объекту, от которого он вызывается.

Сейчас multiprocessing пытается упаковать в pickle целиком ваш объект фрейма, и все что с ним связано (в том числе и окно), чтобы передать в дочерний процесс, и это у него не получается. Чтобы это не происходило, нужно либо сделать `check` отдельной функцией, либо статическим методом.

Вариант с функцией:

```
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool


def check(iter):
    return 'good'


class testing(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        pool = Pool(1)
        iup = pool.map(check, range(1))
        pool.close()

        text = tk.Text(self)
        text.pack()

        text.insert(tk.END, iup)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = testing(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Вариант со статическим методом:

```
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool


class testing(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

        pool = Pool(1)
        iup = pool.map(self.check, range(1))
        pool.close()

        text = tk.Text(self)
        text.pack()

        text.insert(tk.END, iup)

    @staticmethod
    def check(iter):
        return 'good'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = testing(root)
    app.grid()
    root.mainloop()
```

Результат в обоих случаях:

[image: Скриншот]