# Асинхронное ожидание завершения второстепенного процесса

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

Есть главная функция `def start()`, есть функция расчета в другом скрипте `def learning()` (она вызывается из функции `def first()` через multiprocessing - Process) и есть функция вывода результата `def finish()` (она выводит результат из тхт файла полученного из функции `def learning()`)

Мне нужно дождаться завершения расчета и вывести результат, но при этом пока ожидаю мне нельзя блокировать работу основной функции. То есть через `*.join()` мне не подходит, так же проверять на существование файла тхт и в случае, если да, то открыть, тоже не подходит, так как там есть условия связанные с параметрами из главной функции. Как это провернуть?

**First file:**

```
import tkinter as tk
from multiprocessing import Process
from secondFile import learning

class aigodWin(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.combo = Combobox()
        self.combo['values'] = ('1', '2')
        self.combo.current(0)
        self.combo.pack()
        self.btn = Button(text='Start', command=self.start)
        self.btn.pack()

    def start(self):
        proc = Process(target=learning)
        proc.start()
        self.finish() # как-то дождаться завершения proc не блокируя основное окно, чтобы можно было в нем что-то клацать, и только потом запустить эту функцию

    # ..... выполнение других задач

    def finish(self)
        # например условие, держущее меня основном процессе и в этом классе
        if combo.current() == 1:
            # ... вывод результата из тхт файла
            print('FINISH')
        else:
            print('Finish2')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window = tk.Tk()
    app = Win(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

**SecondFile:**

```
def learning():
    #......расчет и запись результата в тхт файл
    print('LEARNING')
```

Comment: Ну собственно ожидайте завершения в отдельном потоке, как я в комментарии к вашему предыдущему вопросу писал. Либо через after периодически проверяйте состояние процесса. В этом ответе примеры после заголовка Multiprocessing: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365

Comment: @insolor я то это попробовал первым делом. Когда он завершается я делаю return, но это ведь не правильно и понятное дело не работает. А обратится к функции последней тоже не могу, так как в новом процессе не знает параметров самой первой функции, а передавать их постоянно тоже не могу, их у меня довольна таки много (в примере просто одна). Буду пробовать через after, надеюсь сработает)