# Проблема с многопоточностью в приложении

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, tkinter, multiprocessing

В общем, я решил создать приложение-таймер, но вот проблема, при использовании многопоточности, я не могу реализовать кнопку сброса таймера, а при использовании дополнительного процесса, оно запускает вторую копию приложения. Можете, пожалуйста помочь, в чем я ошибаюсь и как мне реализовать кнопку сброса таймера?
Вот мой код:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from time import sleep
from datetime import timedelta
from threading import Thread


class Timer():

   def __init__(self, root: Tk):
       self.root = root
       self.has_timer = False

   def make_thread(self):
      # creating a thread to start the timer at the same time as the application
      if self.has_timer:
          messagebox.showerror(message="Timer has already started. Please, stop the previous one first")
        return 
      self.t_thr = Thread(target=self.start_timer, args=(timeInput.get(),))
      self.t_thr.daemon = True
      self.t_thr.start()

  def stop_timer(self):
      self.t_thr.join(0.1)
      timer_label['text'] = "00:00:00"

  def start_timer(self, time):
      # Starting a timer
      if not all(i.isdigit() for i in time.split(':')):
          messagebox.showerror(message="Entered time doesn't match HH:MM:SS format. Please, enter the correct time")
          return
    
      self.has_timer = True
    
      hours, minutes, seconds = map(int, time.split(':'))

      timer = timedelta(days=0, hours=hours, minutes=minutes, seconds=seconds)

      while timer.seconds >= 0:
          timer -= timedelta(seconds=1)
          sleep(1)
          timer_label['text'] = f"{timer.seconds // 3600:02d}:{timer.seconds // 60:02d}:{timer.seconds % 60:02d}"


root = Tk()
timer = Timer(root)
root['bg'] = "#fafafa"
root.title("Timer")
root.geometry('250x200')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False) 
title = Label(root, text='Введите время', bg='gray', font=40)
title.pack()
timer_label = Label(root, text='00:00:00', bg='#ababab', font=40)
timer_label.pack()
timeInput = Entry(root, bg='white')
timeInput.pack()
btn = Button(root, text='Поставить таймер', bg='yellow', command=timer.make_thread)
btn.pack() 
btn = Button(root, text='Сбросить таймер', bg='red', command=timer.stop_timer)
btn.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "я не могу реализовать кнопку сброса таймера" - что конкретно не получается? "а при использовании дополнительного процесса, оно запускает вторую копию приложения." - чтобы второе окно не создавалось весь код снаружи функций вносите в блок `if __name__ == '__main__':`. Но работать напрямую с объектами основного процесса вы не сможете, только через всякие очереди/трубы (Pipe, Queue)

Comment: А зачем вам для такой простой задачи многопоточность?

Comment: Я просто искал хоть какой-то вариант, чтобы всё заработало. Можно сказать, хватался за первую попавшуюся возможность

Comment: И ещё, мне бы хотелось попросить, кому не сложно, написать советы по коду. Мне крайне это интересно, как можно сделать всё лучше и красивее

Comment: insolor, не получается остановить поток.

Comment: Вообще для таймера в tkinter нужно метод root.after использовать, так будет без дополнительных потоков работать. Посмотрите еще вот этот ответ, там несколько вариантов реализации "параллельного" исполнения (root.after, потоки, мультипроцессинг, асинхронность): https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365