# Таймер для ответа в квизе. Python TKinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Всем привеь, мне нужно сделать таймер для игры-квиза на питоне. У меня есть два скрипта:
Первый скрипт - основной:

```
import tkinter as tk
from package import config as set
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from package import timer

def buy_lifes():
    if set.score >= 90:
        set.score -= 90
        set.lifes +=1
        bonus_output.config(text=f"Куплен бонус!", fg="green")
        lifes_label.config(text=f"Жизни: {set.lifes}")
        score_laber.config(text=f"Очки: {set.score}")

    else:
        bonus_output.config(text="У вас недостаточно очков!", fg="red")

def check_answer():
    u_ans = answer_entry.get()

    if u_ans == set.answers[set.current_question]:
        set.score += set.score_for_answer
        set.score += 10
        result_laber.config(text="Правильный ответ!", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
        set.question_generation()
        score_laber.config(text=f"Очки: {set.score}")
        question_label.config(text=set.questions[set.current_question], bg="#27261A", fg='white')
    else:
        result_laber.config(text="Неправильный ответ!", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
        set.score -= 10
        set.lifes -= 1
        lifes_label.config(text=set.lifes)
        if set.lifes < 1:
            window.destroy()
        else:
            set.question_generation()
            lifes_label.config(text=f"Жизни: {set.lifes}", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
            score_laber.config(text=f"Очки: {set.score}")
            question_label.config(text=set.questions[set.current_question], bg="#27261A", fg='white')

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("SQuiz")
result_font = tkFont.Font(family="Segoe UI Semibold", size=20, weight="bold")
question_font = tkFont.Font(family="Segoe UI Semibold", size=17, weight="bold")
result_laber = tk.Label(window, text="Введите ответ, а тут появится статус", bg="#27261A", 
fg='white', font=result_font)
result_laber.pack(ipadx=1920)
question_label = tk.Label(window, text=set.questions[set.current_question], bg="#27261A", 
fg='white', font=question_font)
question_label.pack(pady=10)
answer_entry = tk.Entry(window, bg="#27261A", fg='white')
answer_entry.pack(pady=10, ipadx=1920)
answer_entry.insert(0,'Введите тут свой ответ')
answer_entry.focus()
answer_entry.config(
  borderwidth=0,
  highlightthickness=0,
  relief="solid"
)
submit_button = tk.Button(window, text="Ответить", command=check_answer, bg="#27261A", 
fg='white')
submit_button.pack()
submit_button.config(
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
relief="solid"
)
bonus_label = tk.Label(window, text="Покупка жизней", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
bonus_label.pack(ipadx=1920, pady=10)
bonus_button = tk.Button(window, text="Купить", command=buy_lifes, relief=tk.RAISED, bd=2, bg="#27261A", fg="white")
bonus_button.pack(pady=10)
# Настройка стиля кнопки
bonus_button.config(
font=("Arial", 12),
width=10,
height=2
)
# Настройка закругления кнопки
bonus_button.config(
borderwidth=0,
highlightthickness=0,
relief="solid"
)
bonus_output = tk.Label(window, text="Пока-что не совершались покупки", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
bonus_output.pack(ipadx=1920, pady=10)
lifes_label = tk.Label(window, text=f"Жизни: {set.lifes}", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
lifes_label.pack(ipadx=1920, pady=10)
score_laber = tk.Label(window, text=f"Очки: {set.score}", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
score_laber.pack(ipadx=1920, pady=10)
timer_label = tk.Label(window, text=f"Осталось времени: {timer.seconds}", bg="#27261A", fg='white')
timer_label.pack(ipadx=1920, pady=10)
window.configure(bg="#755A57")
window.mainloop()


while True:
  timer.timer_for_answer()
  timer_label.config(timer.seconds)
```

И второй скрипт - скрипт таймера:

```
import time
from package import config as cfg

seconds = 10

def timer_for_answer():
  global seconds
  while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    seconds -= 1
    if seconds <= 0:
        cfg.TimeIsOut = True
        return
```

Но у меня таймер срабатывает только после закрытия окна, как мне сделать так, чтобы у меня срабатывал таймер **во время** работы программы?

Comment: Вкратце: 1 - все что идет ниже mainloop выполняется после закрытия окна. mainloop выполняется пока окно существует, это цикл обработки событий окна. 2 - вместо циклов используйте метод after или запускайте цикл в отдельном потоке (см. примеры тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365)