# Custom tkinter. Progress Bar как привязать к процессу?

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

В Tkinter связать процент выполнения задачи и progress bar получилось а как мне получить то же в custom tkinter? То есть label должен отображать процент выполнения параллельно прогресс-бару.

```
    # TK
    root = Tk()
    number = 284

    def action_button_1():
        for i in range(number):
            pb.configure(value= i / (number / 101))
            label_process['text'] = f"{int(i / (number / 101))}"
            sleep(0.01)
            pb.update()


    label_process = Label(root, text="")
    label_process.pack()

    button_1 = Button(root, text="Click to Open File", 
                      command=action_button_1)
    button_1.pack()

    pb = Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, 
    mode="determinate", length=500) 
    pb.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    # CTK 
    import customtkinter as ctk
    from time import sleep

    number = 284

    def action_button_open_file():
        value = pb.get()
        for i in range(number):
            pb.set(i / (number / 100))
            label.configure(text = value)
            sleep(0.01)
            pb.update()


    app = ctk.CTk()
    app.geometry("400x150")
    app.grid_columnconfigure((0), weight=1)

    button_= ctk.CTkButton(app, text="Pressed", 
            corner_radius=12,  
            command=action_button_open_file)
    button_.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20,             
            pady=10, 
            sticky="ew", columnspan=2)
    label = ctk.CTkLabel(app, text='0 %', 
    compound='center')
    label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=5,   
             sticky='ew', columnspan=2)

    pb = ctk.CTkProgressBar(app, orientation="horizontal", 
              mode='determinate', determinate_speed=.5)
    pb.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=20,                   
              pady=5, sticky="ew", columnspan=2)
    pb.set(0)

    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ваш код должен быть текстом, а не картинкой.

Comment: Я тут первый раз пока не разобрался как правильно оформлять вопрос

Comment: Михаил, что значит: "Я тут первый раз ...",  если это уже ваш третий вопрос?

Comment: Спасибо что напомнили, действительно я уже заходил давненько, позабыл... да и не знал особо.

Answer (score 0):

Все нормально! Разобрался. Просто не в ту сторону думал, все просто. Так же как в Tk.

```
number = 567
def click_button():
    for i in range(number):
        count = int(i / (number / 101))
        pb.set(count / 100)
        label.configure(text = f'{int(i / (number / 101))} %')
        sleep(0.01)
        pb.update()
```

Comment: Так же как и в Tk - так не нужно делать. Используйте метод after: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633670/1365

Comment: Большое спасибо за информацию.