# Почему зависает while? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я делаю таймер. Переменные: eskolo - количество минут(tkinter.Entry), eskolt - количество секунд(tkinter.Entry).
Функция, вызывающая проблему:

```
def cvv():
eo = int(eskolo.get())
et = int(eskolt.get())
sl = int(eo * 60 + et)
while sl > 0:
    pass
if sl == 0:
    lo.configure(text="Таймер прошел")
```

Comment: while зависает потому что условие выхода из цикла никогда не выполняется. Окно tkinter зависает потому что не должно быть длительных блокирующих операций (например, циклов) в обработчиках, см. [Sleep и while True в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633670/1365)

Comment: * точнее, условие цикла выполняется всегда

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, в питоне имеют значение отступы, а у вас они явно нарушены. Нужно так:

```
def cvv():
    eo = int(eskolo.get())
    et = int(eskolt.get())
    sl = int(eo * 60 + et)
    while sl > 0:
        pass
        if sl == 0:
            lo.configure(text="Таймер прошел")
```

Во-вторых, переменная `sl` в цикле никак не изменяется, условие `sl > 0` всегда будет истинным и цикл будет выполняться вечно.

Таким образом, правильный код:

```
def cvv():
    eo = int(eskolo.get())
    et = int(eskolt.get())
    sl = int(eo * 60 + et)
    while sl > 0:
        sl -= 1
        if sl == 0:
            lo.configure(text="Таймер прошел")
            break
```

Comment: Да, это работает, но мне надо, чтобы он ждал 3сек при этом без sleep, так как мне надо, чтобы не зависало окно.

Comment: @PyArt, это уже отдельный вопрос. К тому же сверху в комментариях insolor уже дал вам ссылку на вопрос, в котором обсуждается, как это сделать.