# While с after Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, while, tkinter-after

Зависает на одном месте, в чем проблема?
Переменные аналогичны с моим предыдущим вопросом ([https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1559138/Почему-зависает-while-python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1559138/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-while-python)).

```
def cvv():
global sl
eo = int(eskolo.get())
et = int(eskolt.get())
sl = int(eo * 60 + et)
while sl > 0:
    def k():
        sl -= 1
        timer.after(1000,k)
    if sl == 0:
        lo.configure(text="Таймер прошел")
        timer.destroy()
```

Comment: Как и в прошлом вопросе: в while у вас в каждой итерации создается фукнция, затем проверяется условие if, которое не выполняется и переходит к следующей итерации. декремент переменной sl никогда не происходит, вот цикл и работает бесконечно

Comment: Вы функцию k определили, но ни разу её не вызываете.

Comment: Вообще, желательно добавлять минимальный рабочий код, чтобы не нужно было догадываться где у вас что.

Comment: * минимальный рабочий и с нормальными отступами, см. справку по оформлению: [Код и предварительно отформатированный текст](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему зависает и как решить проблему когда-то подробно описал здесь: [Sleep и while True в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365), ссылку уже давал вам в комментариях вашему предыдущему вопросу.

В общем-то и код вам нужно переписать аналогично первому же примеру из ответа по ссылке.

Цикл `while` вообще уберите, используйте только планирование следующего запуска функции через метод `after`. Выход из такого "цикла" делайте проверкой текущего значения `st` через `if`, и если условие не выполняется, то просто не вызываете `after`.

Минимальный пример

```
import tkinter as tk


def timer_function(sl):
    if sl <= 0:
        lo.configure(text="Таймер прошел")
        # timer.destroy() # <-- не нужно делать сразу после вывода сообщения, вы так сообщение даже не успеете увидеть
        return
    
    lo.configure(text=sl)  # Выводим текущее значение таймера, чтобы было видно, что что-то происходит
    sl -= 1
    timer.after(1000, timer_function, sl)  # Планируем выполнение функции через 1000 мс, новое значение sl передаем через параметр


def cvv():
    eo = int(eskolo.get())
    et = int(eskolt.get())
    sl = int(eo * 60 + et)
    timer_function(sl)
            

timer = tk.Tk()

eskolo = tk.Entry(timer)
eskolo.pack()

eskolt = tk.Entry(timer)
eskolt.pack()

tk.Button(timer, text="Start timer", command=cvv).pack()

lo = tk.Label(timer)
lo.pack()

timer.mainloop()
```

[image: Анимация]