# Декстоп программа Пайтон зависает

Tags: python, функции, tkinter, while

изучаю библиотеку tkinter и решил написать небольшую программу на проверку пароля. У меня есть функция, которая сверяет пароль и делает разные действия в зависимости от того, что получилось, при введении верного пароля программа работает как надо, но при внесении неверного пароля, программа просто зависает и помогает только выключение окна.
Скрины:[image: ][1]]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Прошу прощения за некорректное размещение вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Sleep и while True в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633670/1365)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот исправленный код, который должен работать правильно:

```
import tkinter as tk

password = "Westyuiopasd"

def get_password():
    global password
    entered_password = enter_password.get()

    if password != entered_password:
        incorrect_password_label = tk.Label(root, text=f'Вы ввели неверный пароль: {entered_password}',
                                            font=('Times New Roman', 18, 'bold'))
        incorrect_password_label.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='we')
        enter_password.delete(0, tk.END)
        incorrect_password_label.after(2000, lambda: incorrect_password_label.destroy())  # Удаление через 2 секунды
    else:
        correct_password_label = tk.Label(root, text="Вы ввели правильный пароль. Вы и в правду любите Ангелину",
                                          bg="blue",
                                          font=('Times New Roman', 18, 'bold'))
        correct_password_label.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='we')
        enter_password.delete(0, tk.END)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("PythonHomework")
root.geometry("1280x750+130+0")

enter_password = tk.Entry(root)
enter_password.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='we')

enter_password_label = tk.Label(root, text='Введите пароль:', font=('Times New Roman', 18, 'bold'))
enter_password_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='we')

enter_password_button = tk.Button(root, text='Ввод', command=get_password, font=('Times New Roman', 18, 'bold'))
enter_password_button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='we')

root.grid_columnconfigure(0, minsize=100)
root.grid_columnconfigure(1, minsize=100)
root.grid_columnconfigure(2, minsize=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: То есть, проблема заключалась в скорости очищения лейбла, я так понимаю. Ну и вы изменили ещё while на if, хотя мне подумалось, что так не сработает.
Спасибо вам большое, вы помогли, впредь буду учитывать это!

Comment: @sunless, проблема в том, что в gui приложениях не должно быть бесконечных циклов, и даже просто долгих задержек перед выходом из обработчиков. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365

Comment: Спасибо, понял.