# После нажатия на кнопку всё зависает и через некоторое время выдаёт только 100% вместо того чтобы проценты постепенно прибавлялись

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import random
root=Tk()
pntgn=Label(root, text="Пентагон")
pntgn.pack()
hehe=Label(root, text=" ")
g=0
def click():
    pntgn.destroy()
    vzlmt.destroy()
    global g
    hehe.pack()
    hehe["text"]="Пентагон взломан на {}%...".format(g)
    for i in range(10):
        time.sleep(random.randint(2, 5))
        g+=10
        hehe["text"]="Пентагон взломан на {}%...".format(g)
vzlmt=Button(root, text="Взломать", 
command=click)
vzlmt.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/633670/sleep-%D0%B8-while-true-%D0%B2-tkinter