Использую threading
Пишу код с модулем threading, запускаю цикл идущий с параллельно открытым окном tkinter, и по завершении цикла должен закрыть окно, но идет какая - то ошибка:
Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
def timer():
    for i in range(1):
        ti -= 1
        sleep(1)
        if ti == 59:
            root2.destroy()
            lab_t.configure(text=ti)
rka = Thread(target=timer)
rka.start()


дубликаты где-то здесь

В данном случае проще переделать на использование метода after. См. тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365
