Последовательность выполнения команд в функции
Почему поле ввода (Entry) появляется только после отрабатывания таймера? Я думал, что в функции myfunc команды выполняются построчно. Т.е. выполняется команда text.config(state="enabled"), поле для ввода становится активным и потом идет отсчет таймера. Почему же тогда поле ввода (Entry) становится активным только после отрабатывания таймера?
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import winsound
import time
import os.path

window = Tk()            
window.title("Test")     
window.geometry("200x50")   

text=ttk.Entry()
text.place(x=20, y=10, width=160)
text.focus_set()

def myfunc():
    text.config(state="enabled")
    time.sleep(3)
      
window.after(10, myfunc)
window.mainloop()


Потому что паузу через time.sleep в tkinter не нужно делать. Все обновления в интерфейсе происходят после выхода из функции, а вы этот выход откладываете этой паузой. Все паузы (отложенные действия) делайте через window.after

GUI однопоточный. Статус вы поменяли чисто как свойство графического элемента, но окно будет перерисовано и это изменение будет отображено только тогда, когда GUI вновь получит управление. А управление он получит только после окончания работы вашей функции, когда закончит работу time.sleep. Именно поэтому не рекомендуется в обработчиках событий GUI делать что-то долгое. А если всё же это нужно, то используются специальные приёмы, чтобы не останавливать обработчик событий GUI при этом. Обычный time.sleep для этого крайне не рекомендуется, вы просто "подвешиваете" GUI при этом.

Спасибо, а какие приемы можно использовать, если в обработке GUI что то долго выполняется?

Посмотрите тут развернутый ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/633842/1365

@winkot Как вам выше подсказали - тот же window.after, который вы уже используете. Или поток отдельный запустить, но только опять же не обычный питоновский, а специальный из tkinter, там вроде должны быть потоки специальные, родные для него.

@insolor В tkinter получается нет своих потоков? Я, наверное, с QT путаю.

@CrazyElf, своих нет, стандартные питоновские можно использовать.
