# if else tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет. Я сделал тригер бот и мне надо его связать с UI, нажимаю на ON - запускается, нажимаю на OFF - процесс убивается.
Вот код -

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox  
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('470x360')  

#fg="#D9B80E"
#bg="#3403BD"

window["bg"] = "#3403BD"

window.iconbitmap('img/logo.ico')

def on_but():
    button = 5

def off_but():
    button = 10

window.title('1')
window.resizable(0, 0)
#label.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Мне нужна помощь в написании условия. Заранее Спасибо.

Comment: Что такое "тригер бот"? Как его создаете?

Comment: тригер бот, это такая програмка для игры, которая отлавливает пиксель и если он равен значению, то она сама выполняет действие (выстрел). мне нужна помощь в написании условия. тригер я сделал.

Comment: Такс, давайте ещё раз и поподробней. Вы хотите сделать что-то типо аима/автострельбы для какой-то игры/проги. Что именно у вас не получается? Захватить нужный пиксель/распознать какой захвачен и тд. Задайте вопрос более корректно. Если скажете для какой именно игры/проги, то помогут ещё быстрее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример с кнопкой button:

```
class Demo:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.flag = True
        self.root = root
        b = Button(root, text='ON/OFF', command=lambda: self.clop(self.flag))
        b.place(x=0, y=0)

    def clop(self, flag):
        if self.flag:
            on_but()
        else:
            off_but()
        self.flag = not self.flag
```

Вам останется лишь адаптировать данный код под ваш

Comment: Если же вы используете `while` то с кодом могут возникнуть проблемы поскольку при использовании циклов окно tkinter зависает, ответ на данную проблему есть здесь:https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/581331/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-label-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b2-tkinter/581537#581537, но это так, на будущее