# Помогите с выводом данных через tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Помогите.
Что не так в коде, при нажатии кнопки инфа выводится в терминале в PC
натолкните на верный ход, пожалуйста
на первом изображении как работает без tkintera
на втором как работает с tkinter[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from tkinter import  *
import pyperclip
import time

window = Tk()

window.title("buffer")
window.geometry('400x250')

def clicked():
    old = ''
    while True:
        s = pyperclip.paste()
        if s != old:
            old = s
            print(s)
        
window = Tk()
window.title("buffer")
window.geometry('400x250')

lbl = Label(text = clicked, justify=LEFT)
lbl.place(relx=.2, rely=.3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: попробуйте window.after(1000,clicked) вместо цикла и слипа. и уточните где должно выводиться ?

Comment: В окне window = Tk()

Comment: добавьте в функцию lbl.config(text=s)  если выводить там. или вам нужно многострочное текстовое поле ?

Comment: Вообщем прога мониторит буфер обмена, и работает в цикле, то что я копирую она выводит в терминале. Я захотел, что бы она не в терминале выводила события, а в окне и попытался завернуть в tkinter, но что то не так идет

Comment: я правил проблему в описании, и убрал кнопку

Comment: В программе с графическим интерфейсом не должно быть бесконечных циклов (в главном потоке). Используйте `window.after`, как вам написали в первом комментарии. См. [Обновление Label из цикла в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581331/1365)

Answer (score 0):

Я не понял суть проблемы, но я вставил то что я непонятно сделал

```py
from tkinter import  *
import pyperclip
import time

window = Tk()
old = ''
window.title("buffer")
window.geometry('400x250')
def clicked():
    global old
    s = pyperclip.paste()
    if s != old:
        old = s
        lbl.configure(text = s)



lbl = Label(window, justify=LEFT)
updating = Button(window, command = clicked, text = " Update")
lbl.place(relx=.2, rely=.3)
updating.place(relx =.2, rely =.4)
window.mainloop()
```

Или же код второй:

```
import pyperclip
import time as tm
import tkinter.messagebox as msg
while True:
    s = pyperclip.paste()
    old = s
    msg.showinfo(message = s)
```