# Интерфейс для программы непрерывного вывода данных с COM порта

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

Написал программу которая непрерывно выводит в консоль данные полученные с COM порта, как вывести эти данные в интерфейс Tkinter? Так как программа выдает данные непрерывно необходимо, насколько я понял создать субпроцесс, но никак не пойму как именно.

```
import serial
import sys

port = serial.Serial(
    port = 'COM4',
    baudrate = 1200,
    bytesize = 8,
    stopbits = 1,
    timeout = 2)

    while True:
        data = port.read_until(expected = chr(10),
size=13)
    #if data[len(data) - 1] == chr(10):
        data = data.decode('ISO-8859-1')
        print(data)
```

Comment: Если просто делать (без отдельного потока/процесса), то заменить цикл на функцию с "перезапуском" через root.after, см ответы тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/633670/1365 и тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/581331/1365

Comment: @insolor стоит отметить что в этом случае нужно сделать неблокирующий read.