# python - tkinter - Динамическое обновление текста из файла

Tags: python, tkinter, gui

Библиотека `tkinter`. Как в `Label` обновлять текст раз в какое-то время?
Задумка в том, что это просто `небольшая консоль` для бота и в ней должен появляться текст из файла, например, `log\log.txt`. Надо сделать так чтобы в переменной `log(tk.Label)` обновлялся параметр `text` каждую секунду или сделать ивент, который замечает изменения в файле

Comment: С чем возникли сложности?

Comment: не понимаю, как постоянно обновлять текст в окне

Comment: См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581537/1365