# Адаптация виджетов под разрешение экрана в Tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

Всем здравствуйте!
Возникла такая проблема: сделал приложение с использованием Tkinter/CustomTkinter. Но, при изменении разрешения монитора, все виджеты сползают кто в лес, кто по дрова. Как это можно исправить ?
Сделать адптивным. Не нашёл подобной функции.

И вопрос по treeview - можно ли как-то, обновлять данные в определёном столбце? Например: столбец 'Цена' - у меня обнавляется каждые 2-3 сек, могу ли я обновить в конкретной строке, только значение цены?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "И вопрос по treeview - можно ли как-то, обновлять данные в определёном столбце?" - можно, через `root.after`: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/581537/1365. Вообще, в вопросе должен быть один вопрос, а не несколько.

Comment: По основному вопросу - нужно смотреть код, чтобы понять, почему у вас все съезжает. То ли смешали pack/grid и place, то ли еще что-то. Скорее всего нужно избавиться от place. "Адаптивный" интерфейс как раз реализуется через pack и grid, а place все по фиксированным координатам размещает.

Comment: Да, всё реализованно через place. И, как я понимаю, не смотря на то, что виджеты размеены  внутри основного окна, это ни чего не значит. И при изменении разрешения экрана, всё будет съезжать ?
Спасибо )
И за второй вопрос тоже )

Comment: По идее при размещении по фиксированным координатам не должно было съехать, но видимо что-то пошло не так. Если использовать grid или pack, то в принципе друг на друга виджеты не смогут накладываться, и размещать можно так, чтобы например таблицы увеличивались автоматически при увеличении окна.

Comment: В целом, как я понима, place() проигрывает pakc и grid. Могут то съехать виджеты, не синхронны с основным окном в общем то .