# Почему так медленно? Зачем тогда потоки?

Tags: python

Есть обычная функция которую я пробовал запускать в потоках и без, в каждом по три раза:

```
import time


def foo(count, num):
    for n in range(count):
        pass
    print('done %s' % num)


start = time.time()
foo(100000000, 1)
foo(100000000, 2)
foo(100000000, 3)
print('Done at:', time.time() - start)
```

Время исполнения 6.2 сек, теперь запускаю ту же функцию в потоках:

```
import threading, time


def foo(count, num):
    for n in range(count):
        pass
    print('done %s' % num)


start = time.time()
threads = []
for n in range(3):
    t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(100000000, n))
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)


for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

print('Done at:', time.time() - start)
```

Время исполнения 7 сек., теперь запускаю с помощью _thread:

```
import time, _thread as thread


def foo(count, num):
    for n in range(count):
        pass
    print('done %s' % num)
    blocks[num] = True


start = time.time()
blocks = [False for n in range(3)]

for i in range(3):
    thread.start_new_thread(foo, (100000000, i))

while not all(blocks):
    pass

print('Done at:', time.time() - start)
```

Здесь вообще почти 10 сек. Почему так ? зачем нужны тогда вообще потоки ели есть эта глобальная блокировка интерпретатора?

Comment: Потоки не расходятся по разным ядрам наверно

Comment: Потоки при GIL отлично ложатся на задачи, большая часть работы в которых идет вне CPU - как правило, это I/O, т.е. чтение файлов и сокетов. Если поток запросил файл и заснул до его возвращения, то  CPU в это время может быть отдан другому потоку, которому есть что делать.

Comment: Возможно, потоки на "реальных" задачах будут вести себя иначе. Такие простые тесты дают не очень полезные результаты. Если вам нужно несколько тысяч потоков, чтобы держать одновременно столько же открытых соединений клиентов с вашим сервером - это одна задача. Если у вас другая задача - вычислительная, то лучше всего сделать число потоков равным числу ядер у процессора и саму ресурсоемкую часть писать уж никак не на интерпретаторе (python).

Comment: http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Почему так медленно?

Только один поток может исполнять Питон-код в любое время из-за GIL (CPython). Поэтому использование нескольких потоков не ускоряет код, подобный приведённому в вопросе, в Питоне.

Пример с `_thread` у вас ещё медленнее из-за `while True` цикла в основном потоке.

> Зачем тогда потоки?

Потоки могут быть использованы не только для улучшения производительности, но для реализации асинхронных вызовов, к примеру, чтобы избежать эффект "подвисания" GUI при выполнении блокирующих вызовов (таких как чтение вывода внешних команд): [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568677/23044).

GIL отпускается во время блокирующих системных вызовов. В частности, тех которые ввод/вывод реализуют — к примеру, это позволяет скачивать несколько веб-страниц одновременно в Питоне. [A very simple multithreading parallel URL fetching (without queue)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27986480/4279).

В тех случаях когда производительность важна, в реальных задачах такие циклы реализованы в C расширениях типа numpy, regex, lxml, sqlite3, или написанных руками на Cython, которые могут отпустить GIL, что может улучшить производительность как на одном ядре на порядок/два, так и позволяет несколько CPU ядер задействовать одновременно.  Вызов С функций через ctypes, также отпускает GIL.

Реализации Питона, в которых нет GIL существуют уже давно (Jython, IronPython). Очевидно, что они не вытеснили реализации, использующие GIL, такие как CPython, Pypy.

Стоит явно упомянуть, что разные Питон-процессы, в частности, такие как созданные с помощью multiprocessing модуля, не разделяют GIL (у каждого процесса  свой GIL). Несколько Питон процессов могут все ядра использовать.

Модель параллельности (concurrency), реализованная на процессах  поощряет разделение данных и использование коммуникации для общения/синхронизации между разными ветками одновременных вычислений, не используя общую память (хотя можно память разделять в некоторых случаях, если необходимо). Это можно суммировать [слоганом из Go языка](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#sharing), на который оказала влияние [CSP теория Хоара (1978)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B):

> Do not communicate by sharing memory; instead, share memory by communicating.