# Как сделать отдельный поток threading на каждую строку?

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Всем привет! вопрос: есть функция, например

```
def printline ():
    for line in file:
       print(line)
```

и есть тхт со строками.
как мне запустить отдельный поток модуля threading для каждой строки? желательно максимально лаконичное решение.
для каждой строки объявить еще одну функцию

```
def work():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=printline)
    t1.start()
```

не получилось, создается только 1 поток с 1 строкой

Comment: сколько у вас строк в файле может быть? Почему вы хотите отдельный поток для каждой строчки? Какую работу планируете над каждой строчкой провести -- зачем потоки использовать?

Comment: @jfs строк может быть много, всегда разное количество, почитав ответы, я сделал вывод, что threading можно использовать для многозадачности в таких процессах, в которых поток может выполняться долго, и пока он выполняется (например загрузка web страницы), threading запускает второй поток, верно?

Comment: Что значит много? 100,10000? Вы пытаетесь  улучшить производительность загрузки многих web-страниц с разных сайтов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
def work(file):
    for line in file:
        threadig.Thread(target=print, args=(line,)).start()
```

Только вот нужно уточнить, что если `file` у вас это не массив, а поток из файла, тогда нужно использовать `readlines`:

```python
for line in file.readlines():
    # Тут делаем что-нибудь с line
```

Comment: потоки будут выполняться параллельно или по очереди?

Comment: параллельно, на то они и потоки

Comment: @Ruberoid А GIL уже отменили?

Comment: @vitidev Хотел бы сказать да, но нет :) Потоки пусть и не выполняются параллельно в строгом смысле слова, но все же это так выглядит. Это же лучше, чем синхронно.

Comment: @Ruberoid а чем лучше?

Comment: @mkkik речь же не идет о производительности, так? Многопоточность нужна в самых различных задачах. В одних лучше синхронно, в других без многопоточности никак.

Comment: не следует использовать `for line in file.readlines()`. `file` уже является итератором по строкам в Питоне. `print` не является потокобезопасной, поэтому всё вперемежку может быть.

Comment: @babyborn: это зависит от того, что вы делаете с каждой строчкой. [Почему так медленно? Зачем тогда потоки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/702448/23044)

Answer (score 1):

использование собственного декоратора, для добавления функций в поток, дает максимально лаконичное решение, в плане длины кода

```
import threading, sys

def thread(func, **t_kwargs):
    '''декоратор выполнения в Thread-потоке'''
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **t_kwargs).start()
    return wrapper

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tprnt = thread(print)  # функция вывода print в потоке
    with open('файл.txt') as iter_text:
        for line in iter_text:
            line = line.rstrip()

            # например, длина обычного принта
            print('1 обычный print', line, file=sys.stdout)

            # вызов print в потоке, не увеличил длину строки
            tprnt('2 print в потоке', line, file=sys.stdout)
            # можно вызывать так
            thread(print)('3 print в потоке', line, file=sys.stdout)
            thread(print, daemon=False)('_4 print в потоке', file=sys.stdout)

            # стандартный способ, самый длинный
            threading.Thread(target=print, args=['4 print в потоке', line], kwargs={'file': sys.stdout}).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Продолжая тему хочу посоветовать для разбора строк `multiprocessing.pool`.

Делается так.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x.upper()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p, open('/proc/cpuinfo','r') as file:
        ret_list = p.imap(f, file)
```

5 - количество процессов. обычно берется по количеству ядер +1.

Если не нужно получать все данные в один лист, то лучше воспользоваться `imap` или map_async. map вернет list, imap возвращает итератор, а map_async передает результат в главный поток для другой функции (например в которой можно реализовать print или отправку данных).