# Как узнать сколько раз и в каком порядке были вызваны функции?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.  Есть такой код, вроде пианино.

`

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pygame import mixer
import time
from collections import deque

root =Tk()

a = int(10)

global Mylist 
Mylist = deque()

def plus():

    global a
    a = int(a)
    a += 30

    c.create_line(0,50,500+a*2,50,width=2,fill="black")
    c.create_line(0,70,500+a*2,70,width=2,fill="black")
    c.create_line(0,90,500+a*2,90,width=2,fill="black")
    c.create_line(0,110,500+a*2,110,width=2,fill="black")
    c.create_line(0,130,500+a*2,130,width=2,fill="black")


def do(event):

    c.create_image(0+a,140,image=DO)
    plus()

    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('1.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    mixer.music.stop()


    Mylist.append(do)


def re(event):

    c.create_image(0+a,130,image=RE)
    plus()

    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('2.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    mixer.music.stop()

    Mylist.append(re) 

def mi(event):
    c.create_image(0+a,125,image=RE)
    plus()
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('2.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    mixer.music.stop()

    Mylist.append(mi)

def fa(event):
    c.create_image(0+a,118,image=RE)
    plus()
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('2.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    mixer.music.stop()

    Mylist.append(fa)

def so(event):
    c.create_image(0+a,105,image=RE)
    plus()
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('2.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    mixer.music.stop()

    Mylist.append(so)

def lu(event):
    c.create_image(0+a,96,image=RE)
    plus()
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('2.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    mixer.music.stop()

    Mylist.append(lu)

def si(event):
    c.create_image(0+a,86,image=RE)
    plus()
    mixer.init()
    mixer.music.load('2.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(2)
    mixer.music.stop()

    Mylist.append(si)

def bu(event):
    root.destroy()

def play(event):
    for play_note in Mylist:
        play_note(event)


A = dict(do=do,re=re,mi=mi,fa=fa,so=so,lu=lu,si=si)

c = Canvas(width=500,height=300,bg="white",cursor="pencil")

c.create_line(0,50,500,50,width=2,fill="black")
c.create_line(0,70,500,70,width=2,fill="black")
c.create_line(0,90,500,90,width=2,fill="black")
c.create_line(0,110,500,110,width=2,fill="black")
c.create_line(0,130,500,130,width=2,fill="black")

pilImage = Image.open("notaall.png")
DO= ImageTk.PhotoImage(pilImage)

pillImageRe = Image.open('notaall.png')
RE = ImageTk.PhotoImage(pillImageRe)

scr = Scrollbar(root)
scr.config(command = c.xview,orient = HORIZONTAL )


but = Button(root,text='Press to destroy window')
but.place(x=0,y=0)
but2 = Button(root,text = 'Press to replay')
but2.place(x =200,y = 0) 
but2.bind('<Button-1>',play)
but.bind('<Button-1>',bu)

root.bind('k',do)
root.bind('s',re)
root.bind('d',mi)
root.bind('f',fa)
root.bind('g',so)
root.bind('h',lu)
root.bind('j',si)
c.pack()
scr.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
`
```

Как корректно исправить ошибку?

Comment: вы хотите хранить последние 8 проигранных нот? Просто в `collections.deque(maxlen=8)` добавляйте ноты, в каждой функции, которая ноту проигрывает (можно декоратор определить, чтобы не дублировать код). А чтобы проиграть, создайте словарик: имя ноты -> функция, которая проигрывает (используйте этот словарь, чтобы при вызове root.bind(), чтобы избежать дублирования и рассинхронизации). Если это не ясно, спрашивайте.

Comment: 1) А как правильно объявить словарь? Вот так не работает:                  ]A = dict([( 'do',do()),('re',re()),('mi',mi()),('fa',fa()),('so',so()),('lu',lu()),('si',si())])                                                                                                                       2) Не совсем понял как в зависимости от данных полученных в collections.deque() проиграются ноты. @jfs

Comment: `dict(do=do, re=re, ..)`. Помните, что если `f` это функция, то `f()` *вызывает* эту функцию в Питоне (и поэтому равно, тому что эта функция возвращает).

Comment: Спасибо,понял как нужно правильно объявить список,но как  в зависимости от данных полученных в collections.deque() проиграются ноты.@jfs

Comment: Вы кладёте сами функции в `history=deque(maxlen=8)`. `history.append(do)` (внутри декоратора это выглядит как `history.append(func); func()` (добавить в историю, проиграть) — если слово декоратор вам ничего не говорит, спрашивайте). Чтобы проиграть всю историю: `for play_note in history: play_note()`.

Comment: Буду очень благодарен если Вы мне еще раз объясните последнее сообщение. И да я не знаю,что такое декоратор. Пробывал ппрочитать(https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/dekoratory.html) но не особо понял.@jfs

Comment: если хочется с помощью кода музыку создавать, то попробуйте http://sonic-pi.net/ (простой код, достаточно приятных результатов позволяет быстро достигать и можно даже в живую с помощью кода импровизировать)

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что у вас в коде есть и другие проблемы. К примеру: не используйте time.sleep() внутри обработчика событий (используйте root.after()) иначе вы "замораживаете" GUI ([Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568677/23044)). По мелочи:  если вы pygame используете, то у него есть функции, которые позволяют и клавиши отслеживать и рисовать (случайный пример: [pygame-piano.py](https://goo.gl/UxnBKa)). В целом, как я упомянул, мне нравится подход в Sonic Pi (play sample, sleep, multiple concurrent loops)

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сохранить последние 8 вызовов, можно использовать [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
import collections

history = collections.deque(maxlen=8)
```

Чтобы сохранить `do` функцию, достаточно написать: `history.append(do)`. Функции в Питоне это обычные объекты: вы можете их хранить в коллекции как и любые другие объекты. `deque(maxlen=8)` используется, чтобы автоматически забывать старые элементы (если вы добавляете 9-ую функцию, то 1-ая автоматически удаляется -- у вас в любой момент не более 8 функций в истории).

Чтобы не изменять каждую функцию отдельно, можно декоратор создать, который возвращает функцию-обёртку, которая добавляет декорируемую функцию в историю перед тем как её вызвать:

```
import functools

def add_to_history(func):
    """Decorator to append *func* to *history* and call *func*."""
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        history.append(func)
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper
```

`functools.wraps(func)` декоратор используется, чтобы сохранить имя декорируемой функции (полезно для отладки).

Опять таки: функции это обычные объекты: вы можете их передавать в качестве аргументов в другие функции, их можно возвращать из функций. Типичное использование декоратора:

```
@add_to_history
def do(_):
    # здесь без изменений
```

Чтобы повторить вызов последних 8 функций, по нажатию на <kbd>k</kbd>:

```
def play_history(event):
    for f in history:
        f(event)

root.bind('k', play_history)
```

Вот полный пример:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import collections
import functools
import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
label = tkinter.Label(root, text='Type any of a,s,d,f,g,h,j,k,q')
label.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

def play_note(note):
    print(note, end=' ', flush=True)
    label.configure(font=(None, 22))
    label['text'] = note.capitalize()

history = collections.deque(maxlen=8)

def add_to_history(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args):
        history.append(func)
        return func(*args)
    return wrapper

def play_history(event):
    for f in history:
        f(event)


notes = "do re mi fa sol la si".split()
for key, note in zip("asdfghj", notes):
    f = lambda event, note=note: play_note(note)
    root.bind(key, add_to_history(f))
root.bind('k', play_history)
root.bind('q', lambda ev: root.quit())
root.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % root.winfo_pathname(root.winfo_id()))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за такой подробный ответ! Пытаюсь вникнуть в Ваш код. Есть одна просьба,делал все как вы говорили,но в моем коде есть маленькая ошибка,можете помочь исправить? @jfs

Comment: @Raccoon ошибка у вас из-за изменения коллекции во время её обхода (вызывается функция из Mylist, которая Mylist изменяет). Или копируйте историю `for f in list(history)` либо как в ответе показано: добавляйте необёрнутую функцию, которая историю не меняет. Не относится к вашей проблеме, но ещё на тему изменения коллекций во время итерации в Питоне: [В чем разница между двумя циклами for: при удалении элементов во время обхода списка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/596463/23044)