# Почему в PyQt данные выводятся в поле только после завершения работы метода, содержащего эти выводы?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt

Имеется следующий код (большая часть опущена):

```
import mymodule


class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(App, self).__init__(parent)
        self.create_widget = CreateFrames(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.create_widget)
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        start = QAction(QIcon('start.png'), 'Начать', self)
        start.triggered.connect(self.start)

        toolbar=self.addToolBar()
        toolbar.addAction(start)

    def print_information(self):
        self.create_widget.textBottom.append('London is the capital of Great Britain')

    def print_errors(self):
        self.create_widget.textBottom.append('Ошибочка вышла!')

    def start(self):
        self.create_widget.textBottom.append('\nНачало работы...')
        mymodule.method1()
        self.print_information()
        mymodyle.method2
        self.create_widget.textBottom.append('Мы на полпути')
        mymodyle.method3
        self.print_errors()
        self.create_widget.textBottom.append('Почти всё')
        mymodyle.method4
        self.create_widget.textBottom.append('Готово')


class CreateFrames(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.initFr()

    def initFr(self):
        self.textEdit = QTextEdit()
```

Проблема в следующем: метод start использует функции подключенного модуля и может выполняться довольно долго. На это время программа "подвисает". Чтобы не пугать этим пользователя, необходимо в процессе работы программы показывать ему некую информацию в одном из окон программы. Но такая задумка не проходит: информация не выдаётся последовательно, а выплёвывается вся после завершения работы метода start. Что можно предпринять?

И есть ли в pyqt какие-либо средства для создания в программе текстового поля-аналога командной строки с выводом туда данных через обычный print, чтобы можно было выводить туда данные из подключенного модуля в процессе выполнения какой-либо его функции?

Comment: Стоит запускать долгий код в QThread.

Comment: Связанный вопрос [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568677/23044)

Comment: Проблема в том что вы блокируете очередь сообщений. После каждой строки кода, которая делает что-то с графическим интерфейсом, можно вставить строку  `Qt.QApplication.instance().processEvents()` для принудительной обработки сообщений, однако это будет "костыльным решением" и лучше, как вам уже и написали, использовать потоки.

Comment: @Avernial Спасибо, пока не разберусь с потоками, воспользуюсь костылями

Comment: связанный вопрос [оконное приложение начинает "Не отвечать" и замораживается при передаче больших данных в момент работы интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786314/23044)