# Разделение на потоки (QThread) в pyqt5

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, qthread, qmovie

Пишу небольшое приложение на *PyQt5*, в котором происходит следующее:

1. После нажатия на кнопку запускается **`.gif`** анимация.
2. Зависание пока выполняется функция (порядка **`5`** секунд).
3. По результату выполнения запускается либо одна, либо другая анимация .

Так вот хочу избавиться от зависания (ужасно напрягает), но никак не пойму как использовать `QThread`? (без передачи числовых данных между классами, т.е. как я понимаю первый поток с анимацией завершается сразу после выполнения потока функции).

Вот упрощенный каркас приложения:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QSize, QRect, QPoint
import  os, random
             
class Wi(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mainsc()
        
    def mainsc(self):
        self.button1 = QPushButton('Click', self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.click)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 300))
        self.button6 = QPushButton('Close', self)
        self.button6.clicked.connect(self.quit_e)
        self.button6.move(370, 300)
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 300))
        self.label.hide()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 330)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()

    def quit_e(self):
        app.quit()

    def click(self):
        self.button1.hide()

        self.animation_load()
        QTimer.singleShot(3600, self.main)
    
    def main(self):
        # функция более сложная - выполняется около 5 секунд (упрощена для примера)
        x = random.randint(1,5)
        y = random.randint(1,5)
        r = (x + y) % 2
        if r > 1:
            self.animation_1()
        else:
            self.animation_2() 
    
    def animation_load(self):
        self.label.show()
        load_p = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'img/load.gif'
        movie = QMovie(load_p)
        self.label.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()

    def animation_1(self):
        my = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'img/y' + str(random.randint(1,3)) + '.gif'
        movie_y = QMovie(my)
        self.label.setMovie(movie_y)
        movie_y.start()

    def animation_2(self):
        mn = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'img/n' + str(random.randint(1,3)) + '.gif'
        movie_n = QMovie(mn)
        self.label.setMovie(movie_n)
        movie_n.start()
            
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Wi()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [оконное приложение начинает "Не отвечать" и замораживается при передаче больших данных в момент работы интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/786314/%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, вопрос приблизительно похожий, но подскажите, пожалуйста, как релизовать Ваш пример в моем коде без передачи чисел/данных между классами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша задача может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import  os
import  random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt, QTimer, QSize, QRect, QPoint,  QThread, pyqtSignal


class SlowTask(QThread):

    signalAnimation1 = pyqtSignal()
    signalAnimation2 = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SlowTask, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        x = random.randint(1,5)
        y = random.randint(1,5)
        r = (x + y) % 2

        QThread.msleep(5000)              # что-то делаем 5 сек, в вашем варианте уберети эту строку

        if r > 0:                         #  -1  +0   !!!
            self.signalAnimation1.emit()
        else:
            self.signalAnimation2.emit()


class Wi(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mainsc()

    def mainsc(self):
        self.button1 = QPushButton('Click', self)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.button1Click)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 300))

        self.button6 = QPushButton('Close', self)
        self.button6.clicked.connect(self.quit_e)
        self.button6.move(170, 300)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 400, 300))
        self.label.hide()

        self.setFixedSize(400, 330)
        #self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.show()

    def quit_e(self):
        app.quit()

    def button1Click(self):
        self.button1.hide()

        self.animation_load()
        QTimer.singleShot(3600, self.main)

    def main(self):
        # функция более сложная - выполняется около 5 секунд (упрощена для примера)
        #x = random.randint(1,5)
        #y = random.randint(1,5)
        #r = (x + y) % 2
        #if r > 0:  #1
        #    self.animation_1()
        #else:
        #    self.animation_2() 
        self.task = SlowTask(self)
        self.task.signalAnimation1.connect(self.animation_1)
        self.task.signalAnimation2.connect(self.animation_2)
        self.task.start()


    def animation_load(self):
        self.label.show()
        load_p = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'img/load.gif'
        movie = QMovie(load_p)
        self.label.setMovie(movie)
        movie.start()


    def animation_1(self):
        my = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'img/y' + str(random.randint(1,3)) + '.gif'
        movie_y = QMovie(my)
        self.label.setMovie(movie_y)
        movie_y.start()
        QTimer.singleShot(3600, self.main)         # запустили анимацию, а что дальше?

    def animation_2(self):
        mn = os.getcwd() + os.sep + 'img/n' + str(random.randint(1,3)) + '.gif'
        movie_n = QMovie(mn)
        self.label.setMovie(movie_n)
        movie_n.start()
        QTimer.singleShot(3600, self.main)         # запустили анимацию, а что дальше?

if __name__ == "__main__":  
    app = QApplication([])
    ex = Wi()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! То что нужно ^_^