# Параллельные вычисления в бесконечном цикле приложения PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, multiprocessing

Всем привет. В питоне 3 есть какое нибудь "best practic" решение по параллельной работе нескольких функций внутри бесконечного цикла PyQt5, которые не блокируют основной цикл приложения и не роняют весь скрипт?

Comment: Чаще всего такие функции запускают в отдельном потоке. Лучше в QThread. Или, если функции неблокирующиеся, можно цикл событий PyQt подменить на цикл событий Twisted и запускать функции в нём.

Comment: О многопоточноси в PyQt уже много написано. Примеры использования можно посмотреть: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-pyqt/840447#840447 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/850016/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-qtread-%D0%B2-pyqt5/850296#850296 , и т.д.

Comment: Можно не много подробнее? Я пример по первой ссылке отличный. Принцип того что он делает именно то что мне нужно. Только я пытаюсь разобраться в коде и не до конца всё понимаю. 

Если не влом объясните по шагам как работает AThread из вот этого примера - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/840239/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-pyqt/840447#840447