# Что делать если при исполнении кода формы pyqt5 зависает

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, многопоточность, pyqt5

Когда выполняется долго код просто не отвечает что нужно делать Там отправка запросов на сайт и обработка

Пример кода с зависанием:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = Qt.QPushButton('Load url!')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def on_clicked(self):
        url = 'https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts'

        self.setWindowTitle('Before load')

        import requests
        rs = requests.get(url)

        self.setWindowTitle('After load: {}'.format(rs))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Проветить на зацикливание, может всё исполняется, просто вы форму визибл не сделали и тд

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [оконное приложение начинает "Не отвечать" и замораживается при передаче больших данных в момент работы интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786314/204271)

Comment: Автор, у вас там случаев нет цикла? Пробовали внутри него вызывать `QApplication.processEvents()`? Или в потоке выполнять цикл?

Comment: Там отправка запросов на сайт и обработка

Comment: Покажите код. А так, я думаю вы не через http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QNetworkAccessManager.html делали запросы. Подвисает весь при отправке запроса? Кст, в комментарии пишите ник, а то человек может не увидеть ответ, например @gil9red

Comment: @gil9red  А что там показывать. Нажима на кнопку отправляется запрос на страницу и выбирается с неё и все и это идет 3 секунды.

Comment: И там сделано не с помощью модулей отправка запросов не на pyqt5

Comment: Вот в этом и проблема. Пока делается запрос и ожидается ответ, текущий поток замирает и приложение перестает отвечать ОС, поэтому ОС показывает что приложение зависло. Добавил пример в вопрос

Comment: А созданием отдельного процесса возможно использование requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Или отправку запроса сделать в отдельном потоке, и через сигнал/слот получить ответ.

Пример:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class LoadUrlThread(Qt.QThread):
    load_finished = Qt.pyqtSignal(object)

    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()

        self.url = url

    def run(self):
        import requests
        rs = requests.get(self.url)

        self.load_finished.emit(rs)


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = Qt.QPushButton('Load url!')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def on_finished_load_url(self, rs):
        self.setWindowTitle('After load: {}'.format(rs))

    def on_clicked(self):
        url = 'https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts'

        self.setWindowTitle('Before load')

        self.thread = LoadUrlThread(url)
        self.thread.load_finished.connect(self.on_finished_load_url)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [QNetworkAccessManager](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QNetworkAccessManager.html#details), он асинхронный, поэтому интерфейс не будет подвисать.

Метод `on_reply_finished` – метод, который будет вызван после того как загрузка будет закончена.

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


class MainWindow(Qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = Qt.QPushButton('Load url!')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)

        self.manager = Qt.QNetworkAccessManager(self)
        self.manager.finished.connect(self.on_reply_finished)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

    def on_reply_finished(self, reply):
        self.setWindowTitle('After load: {}'.format(reply))

    def on_clicked(self):
        url = 'https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts'

        self.setWindowTitle('Before load')

        # Отправляем запрос
        self.manager.get(Qt.QNetworkRequest(Qt.QUrl(url)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()

    app.exec()
```