# Отображение процентов QProgressBar

Tags: python, pyqt5, qthread, qtimer, qprogressbar

Хочу, чтобы процесс расчетов в моей программе на *Python* отображался `QProgressBar`.

Написал класс:

```
class ProgressBar(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 200, 25)
        self.pbar.setValue(0)

        self.setGeometry(400, 300, 280, 170)
        self.setWindowTitle('Updating...')
        self.show()

    def loading(self, percentage):
        self.pbar.setValue(percentage)
```

Экземпляр создается в другом классе, а текущее количество процентов предполагалось передавать через функцию `loading()`.

Самый простой пример:

```
pb = ProgressBar()
for i in range(100):
    pb.loading(i)
    time.sleep(1)
```

В итоге, `ProgressBar` создается, но отображается как пустой виджет до тех пор, пока не наступить **`100%`**, потом закрывается.

Видимо, где-то нужно правильный сигнал указать, попробовал несколько вариантов установить слот и сигнал через `valueChanged()` - не сработало. 
Подскажите, как починить?

Comment: Покажите как вы "передаёте текущее количество процентов через функцию loading".

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [оконное приложение начинает "Не отвечать" и замораживается при передаче больших данных в момент работы интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786314/204271)

Comment: Нельзя тормозить поток оконного приложения и бесполезно изменять интерфейс в цикле.

Comment: не знаю как это будет в питоне, но на C++ надо давать поработать циклу сообщений, т. е. вызывать QCoreApplication::processEvents для отображения изменений

Comment: по вашему наверно надо в цикле вызывать `QApplication.processEvents()`, после `pb.loading(i)`

Comment: @PavelGridin  спасибо! это помогло! работает и без разделения на потоки

Comment: @TheSaGe, в processEvents ещё обычно добавляют аргумент `ExcludeUserInputEvents`, если нужно запретить интерфейсу реагировать на ввод

Answer (score 1):

Тяжелые задачи, как правило работают в отдельных потоках. Из которых переодически передаются данные в графический интерфейс, в том числе и для отображения например в индикаторе выполнения. Но так как неясно, что вы делаете, нет минимального примера, приведу пример демонстрации ProgressBar с использованием QTimer.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *

class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)    
        self.percentage = 0
        self.pbar.setTextVisible(self.percentage)
        self.pbar.setValue(self.percentage)

        button = QPushButton("Старт ProgressBar")
        button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

        self.gridLayout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(button)

    def onClicked(self):
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.ProgressBar)
        self.timer.start(500)

    def ProgressBar(self):
        self.pbar.setValue(self.percentage)
        self.pbar.setTextVisible(self.percentage)
        if self.percentage >= 100:
            self.timer.stop() 
            self.percentage = 0
        else: self.percentage += 5


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.setGeometry(400, 300, 300, 150)
    w.setWindowTitle('Demo ProgressBar')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]