# многопоточность и GUI (Python)

Tags: python-3.x

имеется клиент чата с консольным интерфейсом и работающим в два потока(на прием и передачу сообщений). при попытке прикрутить к этому чуду интерфейс столкнулся с кучей проблем. pyqt ругается, когда я пытаюсь вызвать его функции не из основного потока(я так понял, что весь интерфейс запускается в отдельном потоке). с интерфейсом kivy прога зависает намертво, полагаю, по той же причине. может есть у кого пример похожей многопоточной проги с интерфейсом или кто-то может написать, как правильно прилепить графический интерфейс к моему говнокоду? хоть в какую сторону копать надо? желательно без применения ооп, т.к. с классами и прочими такими штуками я пока плохо знаком.
собсна, сам код:

```
import socket
from threading import Thread


def reception():
    global sock
    while True:
        data = sock.recv(1000000)
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        print(data)


def dispatch():
    global sock
    global login_pwd
    global addr_client

    while True:
        n = input()
        n = '//' + n
        n = n.encode('utf-8')
        sock.sendto(login_pwd + n, addr_client)


global addr_client
addr_client = ('айпи', 9191)

global login_pwd
login_pwd = 'admin//qwerty'

global sock
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

info = login_pwd + '//' + '$$connect'
info = info.encode('utf-8')
sock.sendto(info,addr_client)
login_pwd = login_pwd.encode('utf-8')

tr0 = Thread(target = reception)
tr1 = Thread(target = dispatch)

tr0.start()
tr1.start()
```

Comment: `pyqt ругается` для qt общение между потоками (например, главный поток с gui и побочный) лучше через сигналы-слоты организовывать, пример: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/1a63011d314e490b785de86733b4aeab81105efb/qt__pyqt__pyside__pyqode/pyqt__UpdaterMessageExample__QThread.py

Comment: без использования классов эти сигналы можно как-то отправлять и получать? т.е. просто записать отдельными функциями? уже гуглил по этой теме и везде один и тот же пример с кучей строк кода для ползунка и дисплея.

Comment: Не, сигналы Qt работают только от тех объектов, чьи классы наследованы от QObject или его наследников. А зачем эти трудности с функциями? Язык ООПшный, фрейморк (Qt) тоже ООПшный, проблем с классами не будет

Comment: @СеняСенечкин Qt, как и многие другие GUI-библиотеки, однопоточна. Вы не должны пытаться из потоков взаимодействовать с элементами графического интерфейса - это приведёт к сбою. Вы не должны внутри обработчиков событий запускать потоки - это приведёт к сбою. И вы не должны останавливать поток - это приведёт к сбою. GIL несколько сглаживает масштаб проблемы, но принципиально ничего не меняет. Как правильно подсказал вам gil9red, общение между потоками нужно организовать сигналами. Пример можете посмотреть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/786350/204271).