# Вопрос по потокам в PyQt5

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты, qthread

Хочу попросить вас на примере этого приложения, объяснить как создаются потоки в *PyQt5*.

Есть две функции:

- Первая функция по клику добавляет `datetime.datetime.now()` в `my_list`.
- Вторая функция "**`мониторит`**" `my_list` на предмет изменения.

Подскажите как уйти от "залипания". Я знаю, что я должен использовать `QThread`, но не могу разобраться как.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, Qt
from dis import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
import datetime


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    my_list = []
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function_1)
        self.ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.function_2)

    def function_1(self):
        self.my_list.append(datetime.datetime.now())        

    def function_2(self):
        i = 0
        while True:
            y = len(self.my_list)
            if y > i:
                i = y
                print(i)
```

Comment: вайлтру жестокий)

Comment: Это не важно) написал что попало лишь бы "залипание" было)

Comment: данный пример тредом сожрет проц в 100%
тут лучше что-то асинхронное или синхронизировать потоки.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [оконное приложение начинает “Не отвечать” и замораживается при передаче больших данных в момент работы интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786314/204271)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем очень замысловатом примере использовать QThread можно так:

```
import sys 
import datetime
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
#from dis import Ui_MainWindow

class WorkThread(QThread):
    threadSignal = pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, newList):
        super().__init__()
        self.lenList = 0
        self.newList = newList

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            QThread.msleep(1000)
            if self.lenList != self.newList:
                self.threadSignal.emit(self.newList)
                self.lenList = self.newList

    def clickButton2(self, newList):
        self.newList = newList


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    my_list = []
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
#        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.thread = None

        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.pushButton   = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Append Datetime')
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('мониторить my_list')

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function_1)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.function_2)

        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

    def function_1(self):
        self.my_list.append(datetime.datetime.now())        

    def function_2(self):
        if self.thread is None:
            self.thread = WorkThread(len(self.my_list))
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.start()
        else:
            self.thread.clickButton2(len(self.my_list))

    def on_threadSignal(self, value):
        print(value)    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ваш пост действительно помог разобраться в создании потоков.