# Работа с потоками Python PyQt

Tags: python, многопоточность, pyqt, qt-designer, qthread

На примере простого кода объясните как запустить оболочку программы в одном потоке,а метод `func1` в другом. 
Проблема в том, что при нажатие кнопки пуск оболочка программы не функционирует. Я читал чтобы это устранить нужен запуск через потоки.

**untitled2.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пуск"))
```

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from untitled2 import Ui_MainWindow #untitled2 это название файла где находиться оболочка программы
import sys


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)

    def func1(self): #функция вывода чисел
        for i in range(1000000):
            print(i)


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [оконное приложение начинает “Не отвечать” и замораживается при передаче больших данных в момент работы интерфейса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/786314/204271)

Comment: Не могли бы сделать это на примере моего кода?Мне так легче разобраться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from untitled2 import Ui_MainWindow #untitled2 это название файла где находиться оболочка программы


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 250)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Пуск"))


class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ''' Потоковая задача '''
    threadSignal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)     # Объявляем сигнал, с аргументом(int)  
    threadFinish = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for i in range(10000): 
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(5)
            self.threadSignal.emit(i)
        self.threadFinish.emit()

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)        

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.func1)

    def func1(self):                                     
#        for i in range(1000000): 
#            print(i)
            self.thread = WorkThread()                     # Создаем поток 

            # --- Подключаем сигнал к слоту, слот будет вызываться с параметрами сигнала в нужное время.
            self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
            self.thread.threadFinish.connect(self.threadFinishtd)

            self.thread.start()                            # Стартуем поток  
            self.pushButton.setEnabled(False)

    def on_threadSignal(self, value):                      # функция вывода чисел
        ''' Визуализация потоковых данных-WorkThread.  '''
        self.label.setNum(value)

    def threadFinishtd(self):          
        self.pushButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.label.setText(" {} - Финиш!".format(self.label.text()))


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()  
    window.show()  
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':  
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]