# Как в потоке запустить 2 окна pyqt5?

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt, qthread

Нужно запустить **два** окна в потоке. 
Есть `PyQt` окно, а в нём кнопка. При нажатии на эту кнопку открывается ещё одно окно и в обоих окнах выполняются функции.

Набросал код, но не знаю как добавить в него потоки.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from threading import Thread
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
import threading
import sys


class Example(QMainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
    btn1.move(30, 50)
    btn1.clicked.connect(self.playGif)
    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 290, 150)
    self.setWindowTitle("Event sender")

  def buttonClicked(self):
    Thread(target = self.playGif).start()

  # @pyqtSlot()
  def playGif(self):
    self.cams = WindowGif()
    self.cams.show()

class WindowGif(QDialog):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self.initUI()

  def initUI(self):
    self.movie_screen = QLabel(self)
    self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
    self.movie_screen.setWindowFlags(Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
    self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    self.movie_screen.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
    self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
    self.movie.start()
    self.movie_screen.adjustSize()
# ff1 = f1()
# ff2 = f2()

#   Thread(target = ff1.func1()).start()
#   Thread(target = ff2.func2()).start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = QApplication(sys.argv)
  ex = Example()
  ex.show()
  sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Qt, как и другие GUI-библиотеки, однопоточна. Вы не должны запускать в отдельных потоках окна или обращаться к компонентам графического интерфейса. [Запускайте в потоках функции и шлите из них сигналы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/786350/204271).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets    import *
from PyQt5.QtCore       import *
from PyQt5.QtGui        import *
import threading


class TheThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task, num, obj):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.task = task
        self.num  = num
        self.obj  = obj

    def run(self):
        for i in range(self.num, 100):
            QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
                self.obj, 
                "onTask{}".format(self.task), 
                QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
                QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "Задача {}".format(self.task)),
                QtCore.Q_ARG(str, str(i))     
                )
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(200) 
        QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(
            self.obj, 
            "onTask{}".format(self.task), 
            QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection,
            QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "Задача {}".format(self.task)),
            QtCore.Q_ARG(str, "End")     
            )


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.label   = QLabel()                 
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 450, 200, 100))
        self.label_2 = QLabel()                 
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(750, 450, 200, 100))
        self.cams = None

    def initUI(self):
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Button 1", self)
        self.btn1.move(30, 50)
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.playGif)
        self.setGeometry(525, 100, 290, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle("Event sender")

    def buttonClicked(self):
        threading.Thread(target = self.playGif).start()

    def playGif(self):
        self.cams = WindowGif(self)              
        self.cams.show()
        self.btn1.setEnabled(False)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        if self.cams:
            self.cams.hide()
        self.label.hide()
        self.label_2.hide()
        super(Example, self).closeEvent(event)  

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def onTask1(self, title, text):
        self.label.setText("{} - {}".format(title, text))
        self.label.show()
        if text=="End": self.btn1.setEnabled(True)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def onTask2(self, title, text):
        self.label_2.setText("{} - {}".format(title, text))
        self.label_2.show()


class WindowGif(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()                       
        self.parent = parent
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.movie_screen = QLabel(self)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint | 
                            Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | 
                            Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.movie_screen.setWindowFlags(Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.movie_screen.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.movie = QMovie("loading.gif")
        self.movie_screen.setMovie(self.movie)
        self.movie.start()
        self.movie_screen.adjustSize()


# ff1 = f1()
# ff2 = f2()
#   Thread(target = ff1.func1()).start()
#   Thread(target = ff2.func2()).start()

        self.threadClass = TheThread(1, 10, self.parent) 
        self.threadClass.start()

        self.threadClass2 = TheThread(2, 55, self.parent) 
        self.threadClass2.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]