# Проблема с функцией sleep() и root.after() на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Возникла проблема с функцией sleep() на языке программирования Python. Допустим, я создаю программу виртуального питомца и мне нужно определить для него функцию сна, её название - `sleep_f`. Для этого я программирую следующие действия:

1. Идентификация нужных объектов - `Frame` (это просто чёрный фон) и `Button` (кнопка 'Back')
2. Удаление ненужных объектов - кнопка `Sleep`
3. Появление `Frame`
4. Задержка
5. Появление кнопки 'Back'

Примерный код приведён снизу:

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import random
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
sleep = 50
button = Button(text = 'Sleep', command = lambda: sleep_f())
button.place(x = 0, y = 0)
def sleep_f():
    global sleep
    if sleep < 51:
        sleep_ = Frame(bg = 'black', width = 300, height = 300)
        back = Button(text = 'Back')
        button.place_forget()
        sleep_.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        time.sleep(random.randint(5, 15))
        sleep = 100
        back.place(x = 25, y = 200)
root.mainloop()
```

И вроде бы всё хорошо, но на самом деле нет. Оказалось, что когда я нажимаю кнопку `Sleep`, которая вызывает функцию, кнопка залипает и запускается задержка, а только после неё появляется фон и кнопка 'Back'. А мне требуется так, чтобы сначала появлялся фон, запускалась задержка, и уже после этого появлялась кнопка 'Back'. Надеюсь понятно. Помогите, пожалуйста.

UPD: Попробовал способ с `root.after()`, также безуспешно.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import random
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
sleep = 50
button = Button(text = 'Sleep', command = lambda: sleep_f())
button.place(x = 0, y = 0)
def sleep_f():
    global sleep
    if sleep < 51:
        sleep_ = Frame(bg = 'black', width = 300, height = 300)
        back = Button(text = 'Back')
        button.place_forget()
        sleep_.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        sleep = 100
        root.after(random.randint(5000, 15000), back.place(x = 25, y = 200))
root.mainloop()
```

Что я делаю не так?

UPD: Вопрос решён

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как сделать постоянное обновление окна Tkinter? Как избежать подвисания на время ожидания ответа от сервера](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/723165/204271)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/568677/204271)

Comment: Метод `after` принимает ссылку на функцию, а вы ему передаёте `None`, возвращаемый из вызова метода `place`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот рабочий пример

```py
from tkinter import *
import time
import random
import threading

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x300')
sleep = 50
button = Button(text = 'Sleep', command = lambda: sleep_f())
button.place(x = 0, y = 0)


def timer(timeout, func):
    Timer = threading.Timer(timeout, func)
    Timer.start()
    # timeout - время в секундах
    # func - функция которая выполнится после истечения времени

def wakeup():
    global sleep
    sleep = 100
    back = Button(text = 'Back')
    back.place(x = 25, y = 200)

def sleep_f():
    global sleep
    if sleep < 51:
        sleep_ = Frame(bg = 'black', width = 300, height = 300)
        sleep_.place(x = 0, y = 0)
        timer(random.randint(5, 15), wakeup)

root.mainloop()
```