# Как передавать данные из дополнительного потока в основной поток?

Tags: python, ооп, многопоточность, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты

Долго бьюсь над задачей передавать значение из дополнительного потока значение в *GUI* поток, изменяя *GUI* элемент на передаваемое значение. 
Но как я не пытаюсь, программа крашится при выполнении этого действия. Притом если делать тоже самое из GUI поток, то все исправно.
GUI код отдельно, могу приложить если нужно. Тыкните пожалуйста носом, где я туплю

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal
import MiScanUi
import sys

class secondFlow(QtCore.QThread): # 2 поток с автозапуском метода run при старте потока
    signalFromSecondFlow = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def run(self): #автоматически запускается при старте потока
       n = 1
       while n > 0:
           print('поточу поточу')
           n = n+1
           print(n)
           self.signalFromSecondFlow.emit(n)
           #self.msleep(1000)

class GUImainThread(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, MiScanUi.Ui_mainWindow):

      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super().__init__(parent)
          self.ui = MiScanUi.Ui_mainWindow()
          self.ui.setupUi(self)

          self.secondThread = secondFlow()
          self.secondThread.signalFromSecondFlow.connect(self.changeText)

          self.secondThread.start()

      def changeText(self, text):
          self.curpage_count.setText(5)
          print('pololo')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    win= GUImainThread()  # Создаём объект класса GUiExampleApp
    win.show()  # Показываем окно
    sys.exit(app.exec_()) # и запускаем приложение
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Мультизадачность на Python: выполнить две долгие функции одновременно, не блокируя GUI](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568677/%d0%9c%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QLabel::[**setNum(int num)**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#setNum)
>
> Задает для содержимого метки обычный текст, содержащий текстовое представление целого числа. 
> Любое предыдущее содержимое очищается. 
> Ничего не делает, если строковое представление целого числа совпадает с текущим содержимым метки.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, Qt

#import MiScanUi


class secondFlow(QtCore.QThread):  # 2 поток с автозапуском метода run при старте потока
    signalFromSecondFlow = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def run(self): # автоматически запускается при старте потока
       n = 1
       while n > 0:
           #print('поточу поточу')
           n = n + 1
           #print(n)
           self.signalFromSecondFlow.emit(n)
           self.msleep(100)


class GUImainThread(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):   # , MiScanUi.Ui_mainWindow):
      def __init__(self, parent=None):
          super().__init__(parent)
#          self.ui = MiScanUi.Ui_mainWindow()
#          self.ui.setupUi(self)
          
          self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
          self.centralWidget.setStyleSheet('background-color: #9EB23B;')
          self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
          
          self.curpage_count = QtWidgets.QLabel()
          self.curpage_count.setStyleSheet('''
              background-color: green; 
              color: #FFC54D;
              font: 50pt \"Ubuntu\";
          ''') 
          
          layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
          layout.addWidget(self.curpage_count, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)

          self.secondThread = secondFlow()
          self.secondThread.signalFromSecondFlow.connect(self.changeText)
          self.secondThread.start()

#     def changeText(self, text):
#                          v^v^  
      def changeText(self, num ):                                        # !!! +++
# TypeError: setText(self, str): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
#          self.curpage_count.setText(5)

          self.curpage_count.setNum(num)                                 # !!! +++
          
          #print('pololo')
          

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    win = GUImainThread()  
    win.show()  
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Наверно будет важна обратная связь от меня. Описанную ошибку с int и str я сделал в ходе экспериментов(извиняюсь что сюда залил с ней), действительная проблема моей ситуации была в неправильном подтягивании класса с GUI(вернееaормирование самого доп. файла с GUI), т.к. даже с исправленным кодом краш сохранился. Но благодаря вашим правкам я понял, что нужно рыть в другую сторону, и таки разобрался в ситуации и теперь у меня есть рабочий многопоточный шаблон на будущие проекты. Благодарю за ответ!